# Putting uncommitted changes at Master to a new branch by Git

Tags: git, branch

How can you put uncommitted changes to a branch TEST when I am at the branch `master`?

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2944469/how-to-commit-my-current-changes-to-a-different-branch-in-git

Answer (score 151, accepted):

You can just checkout to the test branch and then commit. You don't lose your uncommited changes when moving to another branch.

Supposing you are at the master branch:

```
git checkout test
git add .
git add deletedFile1
git add deletedFile2
...
git commit -m "My Custom Message"
```

I am not really sure about the deleted files, but I guess they aren't included when you use `git add .`

Comment: Sometimes the checkout will fail because your changes conflict with that branch. You can try checkout -m to merge.

Comment: I tried this but I got an error :
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by checkout. Please, commit your changes or stash them before you can switch branches.

Comment: While this will work, the answer which says use stash should be preferred, IMO. Maybe just personal choice, but it is a cleaner workflow, logically and introduces STASH which is a useful command.

Comment: The option "-b" is missing, as the headline suggests that the question is concerning a "new" branch.

Answer (score 195):

Also you can create a new branch and switch to it by doing:

```
git checkout -b new_branch
git add .
```

I use this all the time because I always forget to start a new branch before I start editing code.

Comment: same issue as @jouni noted for the other answer - you can run into difficulty merging the branch back into master if additional changes conflict with original changes. IMO this thread answers the question better: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/556923/git-how-to-merge-my-local-working-changes-into-another-branch

Comment: Short, sweet and reassuring ... "I use this all the time..."

Comment: Don't forget to do commit in the new_branch. If you switch back to the master branch and revert changed files, you will lose them in the new_branch too.

Answer (score 36):

Why not just use git stash. I think it's more intuitive like a copy-and-paste.

```
$ git branch
  develop
* master
  feature1
  TEST
$
```

You have some files in your current branch that you want to move.

```
$ git status
# On branch master
# Changes to be committed:
#   (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
#
#      modified:   awesome.py
#
# Changed but not updated:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#
#      modified:   linez.py
#
$
$ git stash
Saved working directory and index state \
  "WIP on master: 934beef added the index file"
HEAD is now at 934beef added the index file
(To restore them type "git stash apply")
$
$ git status
# On branch master
nothing to commit (working directory clean)
$
$
$ git stash list
stash@{0}: WIP on master: 934beef ...great changes
$
```

Move to the other branch.

```
$ git checkout TEST
```

And apply

```
$ git stash apply
# On branch master
# Changed but not updated:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#
#      modified:   awesome.py
#      modified:   linez.py
#
```

I also like `git stash` because I use `git flow`, which complains when you want to *finish* a feature branch whilst having changes still in your working directory.

Just like @Mike Bethany,  this happens to me all the time because I work on a new problem while forgetting I am still on another branch. So you can *stash* your work, `git flow feature finish...`,  and `git stash apply` to new `git flow feature start ...` branch.

Comment: `git stash` is my preferred way of dealing with uncommitted changes. It's certainly an intuitive method when you think of it as cut and paste.

Comment: This seems a good approach to me. It worked without a problem.

Comment: Didn't know you could do this and it worked nicely. Feels a bit more intuitive than the other methods.

Comment: I think stashing it's more professional way, instead of using git checkout and then add. I think your answer should be 100+ votes.

Comment: git stash doesn't work if you have a new uncommitted file.

Comment: @Καrτhικ `git stash --include-untracked`

Comment: In which branch stash has been applied? test or master? It seems checked out to test branch but showing master?

Answer (score 5):

```
git checkout TEST
git add file1 file2
git commit
```