# How can I switch to another branch in Git?

Tags: git, version-control, git-checkout

Which one of these lines is correct?

```
git checkout 'another_branch'
```

or

```
git checkout origin 'another_branch'
```

or

```
git checkout origin/'another_branch'
```

And what is the difference between them?

Comment: `git checkout [branch]` for most users coming to this question

Comment: here is the quick answer `git switch branch-name` it is a new way of doing it. Again `git checkout branch-name` is still supported and working.

Comment: In 2017? There must be many, many other Stack Overflow questions with that exact same question. Where are they?

Comment: Related: *[What's the difference between 'git switch' and 'git checkout' <branch>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57265785/whats-the-difference-between-git-switch-and-git-checkout-branch)*

Answer (score 415, accepted):

If `another_branch` already exists locally and you are not on this branch, then `git checkout another_branch` switches to the branch.

If `another_branch` does not exist but `origin/another_branch` does, then `git checkout another_branch` is equivalent to `git checkout -b another_branch origin/another_branch; git branch -u origin/another_branch`. That's to create `another_branch` from `origin/another_branch` and set `origin/another_branch` as the upstream of `another_branch`.

If neither exists, `git checkout another_branch` returns error.

`git checkout origin another_branch` returns error in most cases. If `origin` is a revision and `another_branch` is a file, then it checks out the file of that revision but most probably that's not what you expect. `origin` is mostly used in `git fetch`, `git pull` and `git push` as a remote, an alias of the url to the remote repository.

`git checkout origin/another_branch` succeeds if `origin/another_branch` exists. It leads to be in detached HEAD state, not on any branch. If you make new commits, the new commits are not reachable from any existing branches and none of the branches will be updated.

**UPDATE**:

As 2.23.0 has been released, with it we can also use `git switch` to create and switch branches.

If `foo` exists, try to switch to `foo`:

```
git switch foo
```

If `foo` does not exist and `origin/foo` exists, try to create `foo` from `origin/foo` and then switch to `foo`:

```
git switch -c foo origin/foo
# or simply
git switch foo
```

More generally, if `foo` does not exist, try to create `foo` from a known ref or commit and then switch to `foo`:

```
git switch -c foo <ref>
git switch -c foo <commit>
```

If we maintain a repository in Gitlab and Github at the same time, the local repository may have two remotes, for example, `origin` for Gitlab and `github` for Github. In this case the repository has `origin/foo` and `github/foo`. `git switch foo` will complain `fatal: invalid reference: foo`, because it does not known from which ref, `origin/foo` or `github/foo`, to create `foo`. We need to specify it with `git switch -c foo origin/foo` or `git switch -c foo github/foo` according to the need. If we want to create branches from both remote branches, it's better to use distinguishing names for the new branches:

```
git switch -c gitlab_foo origin/foo
git switch -c github_foo github/foo
```

If `foo` exists, try to recreate/force-create `foo` from (or reset `foo` to) a known ref or commit and then switch to `foo`:

```
git switch -C foo <ref>
git switch -C foo <commit>
```

which are equivalent to:

```
git switch foo
git reset [<ref>|<commit>] --hard
```

Try to switch to a detached HEAD of a known ref or commit:

```
git switch -d <ref>
git switch -d <commit>
```

If you just want to create a branch but not switch to it, use `git branch` instead. Try to create a branch from a known ref or commit:

```
git branch foo <ref>
git branch foo <commit>
```

Comment: This answer is correct (as usual, and upvoted), but I'll add a comment that *may* be helpful: the `git checkout` command does too many things, in my opinion. That's why there are so many modes of operation here. If the only thing `git checkout` did was *switch* branches, the answer would be simple, but it can also *create* branches, and even extract files from specific commits *without* switching branches.

Comment: this is the right answer, but shows how git is kinda screwed up in command line.  git checkout to switch branch?

Comment: @thang Well, with release 2.23.0, this is remedied: you can now use `git switch` to switch to a branch.

Comment: Switch doesn’t seem to work for this version of git.  What do I use to switch to a different branch in this version of git?
C:\widget>git --version
git version 2.11.0.windows.3

C:\widget>git switch master
git: 'switch' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.

C:\widget>

Comment: @John use `git checkout` instead for old versions, which also works in modern versions.

Comment: I'm confused by many of the answers to this question. If I already have a branch b1 checked out does checking out another branch b2 replace the files of b1 (where they differ)? If not, how do I actually get the files of b2 into my folder?

Answer (score 94):

Switching to another branch in Git. Straightforward answer,

git-checkout - Switch branches or restore working tree files

```
git fetch origin         # <---- This will fetch the branch
git checkout branch_name # <---  Switching the branch
```

Before switching the branch, make sure you don't have any modified files. In that case, you can commit the changes or you can stash it.

Comment: The last command gets me into detached HEAD state. Means one cannot edit the branch.

Comment: The branch your trying to checkout is not fetched then you need to fetch before checkout. You can skip the fetch if the branch is upto date then just use git checkout branchname.

Comment: Wouldn't it be sufficient to perform a "git pull" after having switched to the branch?

Comment: pull also ok, pull does the fetch and merge together in the background. I don't see any diff.

Answer (score 48):

Useful commands to work in daily life:

```
git checkout -b "branchname" ->  creates new branch
git branch                   ->  lists all branches
git checkout "branchname"    ->  switches to your branch
git push origin "branchname" ->  Pushes to your branch
git add */filename           -> Stages *(All files) or by given file name
git commit -m "commit message" -> Commits staged files
git push                     -> Pushes to your current branch
```

If you want to merge to dev from feature branch,
First check out dev branch with command "**git branch dev/develop**"
Then enter merge commadn "**git merge featurebranchname**"

Comment: Thanks Bro, краткость сестра таланта next to reply above)

Comment: Simple yet useful guide. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 22):

[`git checkout "branch_name"`]

is another way to say:

[`git checkout -b branch_name origin/branch_name`]

in case "branch_name" exists **only** remotely.

[`git checkout -b branch_name origin/branch_name`] is useful in case you have multiple remotes.

Regarding [`git checkout origin 'another_branch'`] I'm not sure this is possible, AFAK you can do this using "fetch" command 
-- [`git fetch origin 'another_branch'`]

Comment: I know the command "git checkout -b branchName" for creating another branch. This was not the question!

Answer (score 18):

With [Git 2.23](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/git/git/master/Documentation/RelNotes/2.23.0.txt) onwards, one can use `git switch <branch name>` to switch branches.

Comment: Holy s**t, this is a game changer. Slightly related, you can use `git restore` for what checkout did to files.

Answer (score 9):

What worked for me was the following:

Switch to the needed branch:

```
git checkout -b BranchName
```

And then I pulled the "master" by:

```
git pull origin master
```

Answer (score 6):

Check: `git branch -a`

If you are getting only one branch, then do below steps.

- Step 1 : `git config --list`
- Step 2 : `git config --unset remote.origin.fetch`
- Step 3 : `git config --add remote.origin.fetch +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*`

Comment: I wonder how this series of commands would switch to another branch.

Comment: This might be useful to do when you did a _shallow clone_ (using the `depth` param) previously and now wonder why you cannot fetch another remote branches getting the `error: pathspec 'another_branch' did not match any file(s) known to git` using the commands suggested above. It is surely not what the original question was about but it can help others scratching their heads here.

Comment: This is what I needed to do, before running `git switch -t origin/branchname`. I'm not entirely sure what the last command did, but it seemed my `remote.origin.fetch` was only looking at `+refs/heads/current_branch:refs/remotes/origin/current_branch` so was not aware any other branches existed (I was getting the error `fatal: invalid reference: origin/branchname` previously)

Comment: What do you mean by "getting only one branch"? "have one branch?" "got only one branch"?

Comment: OK, the OP has [left the building](https://www.explainxkcd.com/wiki/index.php/979:_Wisdom_of_the_Ancients): *"Last seen more than 5 years ago"*

Answer (score 6):

If you want the branch to track the remote branch, which is very important if you're going to commit changes to the branch and pull changes etc, you need to add a `-t` for the actual checkout like so:
`git checkout -t branchname`

Answer (score 5):

To switch to an branch with your changes, you should do a fetch first. This is to save the changes like your *[package.json](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/configuring-npm/package-json/)* or your ***.env*** files.

So:

`git fetch`

And then:

`git checkout <new branch>`

This answer is for those which where stuck for a while, like me.

Answer (score 3):

Switching to another branch in Git can be done with a single command.

`git switch branch-name`

Comment: Yes, but does that answer the question? Three options were presented and the one in this answer is not one of them. *Why* is that? That ought to be addressed.

Answer (score 2):

I am using this to switch one branch to another one you can use. It works for me like charm.

```
git switch   [branchName]
```

or

```
git checkout [branchName]
```

Example:

```
git switch develop
```

or

```
git checkout develop
```

Answer (score 1):

**Check remote branch list:**

```
git branch -a
```

**Switch to another Branch:**

```
git checkout -b <local branch name> <Remote branch name>
Example: git checkout -b Dev_8.4 remotes/gerrit/Dev_8.4
```

**Check local Branch list:**

```
git branch
```

**Update everything:**

```
git pull
```

Answer (score 0):

These are the steps I follow:

- git clone {link}
- cd {repo folder}

You can check the status and which branch you are on using:

- git status
- git branch
- git branch -a

Note: Here if you make changes in your local repo before moving to the new branch, the following steps should still work.

If "git branch" shows master, and you want to create+move to another branch:

- git checkout -b {branch name}

Check branch again using "git branch"
It should now show that you are in the new branch.

Now add, commit and push:

- git add .
- git commit -m "added new branch"
- git push origin {branch name}

The above steps work for me in both the situation when I have made changes before moving to the new local branch or making changes after moving to the new branch.
I hope it helps people running into similar situations and it is also the solution to the question mentioned here: [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2944469/how-to-commit-my-current-changes-to-a-different-branch-in-git/2945904)