# Can not see the commits for pushing in Pycharm

Tags: git, pycharm

[image]

I've made some commits but I can not see them for the push.

I've read this may be related to not having a remote? But here is the result of the command line:

```
$ git remote
origin
```

**UPDATE:**

**git status** command result:

```
git status
HEAD detached from 5235085
Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

    .idea/
    Connect4Py/__pycache__/

nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
```

**git branch -avv** command result:

```
git branch -avv
* (HEAD detached from 5235085) 908eb97 Fix: - New camera OpenCV configurations      - Improved the Yellow and Red Ball detections.      - Improved the Matrix placement of the balls.
  main                         6dc0b73 [origin/main] Fix: bug fixes
  temp                         1e084c0 Fix: - New camera OpenCV configurations      - Improved the Yellow and Red Ball detections.      - Improved the Matrix placement of the balls.
  remotes/origin/HEAD          -> origin/main
  remotes/origin/main          6dc0b73 Fix: bug fixes
```

Note: The `fix: bug fixes` commit was not made by me, that was another user and his commit-push commands were successful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Still in command-line, check the output if `git status`

If you are in detached HEAD mode (not in a branch), check your local and remote branches (`git branch -avv`), and see which one you should be on.
You can then [switch to the right branch, and merge your detached HEAD](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39197098/6309).

```sh
git switch -c tmp
git switch main
git merge tmp
git branch -d tmp
```

For older Git:

```sh
git checkout -b tmp
git checkout main
git merge tmp
git branch -d tmp
```

From there, you will be able to push, including from PyCharm.

Comment: Sorry, I am really new to these stuff. I updated my question, can you please explain what to do from there step by step?

Comment: @noobie No problem. I have edited the answer accordingly.

Comment: I get git: 'switch' is not a git command. error. I checked and updated the git: git is already the newest version (1:2.17.1-1ubuntu0.9) but still can not use the switch command. I've looked this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47630950/how-can-i-switch-to-another-branch-in-git but I am too afraid to use the commands since the project is really big and there are other contributers

Comment: @noobie 2.17? I wasn't born yet. Can you try and upgrade to 2.34.1? https://stackoverflow.com/a/41357503/6309

Comment: @noobie If no upgrade possible, I have edited the answer with the old commands for older Git.