# Moving some uncommitted changes to a new branch

Tags: git, git-branch

I'm working on a new private (local) branch called `TOPIC` implementing a new feature.  After working on this new feature for a while, I realized that some of the stuff that I wrote really should be in it's own branch, `GIZMO`.  But I also have uncommitted files that should not be part of `GIZMO`

So lets say that I have the following files that haven't been committed:

```
foo/a.cpp
foo/b.cpp
foo/c.cpp
feature/magic.cpp
feature/unicorns.cpp
feature/gold.cpp
```

What I want to do is create a new topic branch `GIZMO` consisting of `foo/*`, so that I can commit that and merge it back to `master`, and then continue working on `TOPIC`.

This is different than [other](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1351567/241536) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1351567/2944469) I [have](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1394797/241536) seen, because in those questions a new branch was being created from *all* uncommitted changes, and that's not what I want to do here.  Here, I only want to make a new branch out of *some* of my uncommitted changes.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you commit what you want, stash your un-commited changes.  Make a new branch, pop the stash, commit the changes, switch back to whatever branch you want?

So for your example, commit your `feature/*` files.  Stash your `foo/*` files.  Switch to a new branch based off Master.  Pop your stash, which should only be `foo/*` files.  Commit those to your new branch, then switch back to Master.

If you don't want to commit your `feature/*` files first, then stash everything, commit only `foo/*` on the new branch.  Make another new stash for `feature/*` files again, and re-pop that when you switch back to Master.

Comment: I *could*, but I'm using a branch naming scheme in such a way that the `GIZMO` stuff doesn't match the (real) name I have for `TOPIC`.  I'd prefer to create a whole new branch out of just some of the uncommitted stuff.

Comment: I don't see how a branch naming scheme will prevent you from stashing/switching/popping.  Are the file names themselves different?

Comment: Oh, and also, the `feature/*` files aren't really in a state where I'd want to commit them now.  Sometimes I might be able to `--amend` the commit later, but I was hoping for a more direct solution.

Comment: Your edit clarified some misunderstandings I had about what you were suggesting.  This may actually work better than I initially thought.

Comment: Then stash everything and only commit the `foo/*` files.  Re-stash the `feature/*` files and pop back on Master.

Comment: If my answer helped you solve your problem, would you mind accepting it? If not, not a big deal.

Comment: No of course u would not mind at all, and I will. I just wanted to see if I could solicit some other answers first.  Thanks for your answer.