# Move existing, uncommitted work to a new branch in Git

Tags: git, git-branch, git-stash, git-reset

I started some work on a new feature and after coding for a bit, I decided this feature should be on its own branch.

How do I move the existing uncommitted changes to a new branch and reset my current one?

I want to reset my current branch while preserving existing work on the new feature.

Comment: The same interesting subject https://stackoverflow.com/q/556923/269514 ?

Answer (score 4610, accepted):

#### Update 2020 / Git 2.23

Git 2.23 adds the new [`switch`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-switch) subcommand in an attempt to clear some of the confusion that comes from the overloaded usage of [`checkout`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout) (switching branches, restoring files, detaching HEAD, etc.)

Starting with this version of Git, replace the checkout command with:

```
git switch -c <new-branch>
```

The behavior is identical and remains unchanged.

---

#### Before Update 2020 / Git 2.23

Use the following:

```
git checkout -b <new-branch>
```

This will leave your current branch as it is, create and checkout a new branch and keep all your changes. You can then stage changes in files to commit with:

```
git add <files>
```

and commit to your *new branch* with:

```
git commit -m "<Brief description of this commit>"
```

The changes in the working directory and changes staged in index *do not belong to any branch* yet. This changes the branch where those modifications would end in.

You don't *reset* your original branch, it stays as it is. The last commit on `<old-branch>` will still be the same. Therefore you `checkout -b` and then commit.

Comment: Just to make sure, I need to commit the unfinished feature BEFORE I reset my original branch? Or will those uncommitted files be preserved regardless of committing?

Comment: FYI: changes in working directory and changes staged in index do not belong to a branch. `git checkout -b <new branch>` changes where those changes would end in.

Comment: If you already have a branch and want to move your changes to the existing branch, checkout http://stackoverflow.com/questions/556923/git-how-to-merge-my-local-working-changes-into-another-branch

Comment: If you want to push your new branch to the remote repository: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2765421/how-to-push-a-new-local-branch-to-remote-repo-and-track-it-too

Comment: I dont know this basic fact.. "The changes in the working directory and changes staged in index do not belong to any branch yet". I was about to do this task manually. This answer is very handy!

Comment: @thedeeno, it would seem so.  I just did `git checkout -b <new-branch>`, then without commiting, switch back to main branch and `git checkout -- <modified file>` and it blew away changes on both branches. :(  No big deal, not many changes, but lesson learned.

Comment: It's worth noting that changes that have been **added** but not **committed** on the old branch will be moved painlessly to the new branch.

Comment: "This changes where those changes would end in." Can't understand this. Could anybody please explain?

Comment: @NickVolynkin: checkout changes/switches the branch your edits will be committed to.

Comment: @knittl: Oh. Thank you, now I see it. ) "This changes the branch where those changes would end in".

Comment: what if I get this `error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by checkout:` when I try to switch branches?

Comment: @maahd: this means you have changes in files that have changed between branches. Git cannot merge these changes automatically, so you have to commit, stash, or remove them.

Comment: @DaneO'Connor, yes it appears you must commit the unfinished feature BEFORE you reset your original branch, otherwise the uncommitted changes will be wiped out in both branches when you do `git checkout -- .` or `git checkout .` I'm surprised nobody commented about this already.

Comment: @JDSmith: uncommit changes _do NOT_ belong to any branch. They only reside in the working directory `git checkout .`/`git reset --hard` will unrecoverably **remove** them

Comment: will this answer work if I'm not working on master originally? i.e. I'm on one feature branch, realized it's the wrong one and want to move my work to another feature branch?

Comment: @maahd: you can then simply checkout the other branch (without the `-b` flag). If the files in question were not changed between the branches were not edited, it will work fine. However, if they were edited, git checkout will abort and you will have to stash/checkout/unstash.

Comment: i had a quick question, when i create a new branch, will all unstaged be still there as you said as well as the changes to be committed, or should I unstage them first?  I have files staged to be added, but im not sure if i should unstage them, and then change branches, then stage everything

Comment: @Fallenreaper: all staged/unstaged/untracked files will keep their status.

Comment: What if I have already run `git add  .`, how do I move the files to a new branch?

Comment: @RazvanZamfir exactly as written in the answer `git checkout -b new-branch-name`

Comment: What if the commit was/is _already_ made, on the master: `git commit -m "My New Feature"` and I want to move it (the commit with _all its files_) on a new branch `my_ new_feature_branch`?

Comment: @RazvanZamfir create a new branch (either `git branch new-branch` or `git checkout -b new-branch` to switch branches immediately). You will then have a new branch exactly at the commit you want. If you do not want to have the commit on the master branch, you have to move that branch back one commit, either using `git branch -f master master^` or `git checkout master && git reset (--hard) master^` (careful, `reset --hard` will delete all local changes irrevocably)

Comment: `Please commit your changes or stash them before you switch branches.
Aborting`

Comment: @ScottyBlades is that a question or is it supposed to be a helpful comment? This message is only shown when you switch to a different existing branch (`git checkout branch`), not when creating a new branch on the current HEAD commit (`git checkout -b branch`). Note the `-b` switch

Comment: That’s the read when I attempted the steps provided without other steps.  It’s my understanding that when using git checkout -b branch, not only is a new branch created, but current branch switches to the newly created branch.

Comment: @ScottyBlades, yes the new branch is created and then checked out. If you you enter the the command exactly as presented in the answer, it is not possible to get the error, because the _commit_ of HEAD remains unchanged. The only thing I can think of is if you tried to run `git checkout -b newbranch different_ref` – but that's *not* what my answer recommends. IF you executed my command as recommendend and still get the error (I doubt it), please let me know, I'd have to dig into it. Could you then provide a MWE?

Comment: The latest git version in Ubuntu apt-get is 2.17.1. So, the switch command is still too bleeding edge to be the top answer, IMHO.

Comment: It would be helpful to explain what the -c parameter does for the `git switch` cmd, does it create a new branch?

Comment: @JónTraustiArason yes, it does. I assumed people would be able to read the documentation of the commands if they needed more details. And since the question was specifically about creating a new branch, I didn't bother explaining that the command will in fact create a new branch – will update the post to link the online docs.

Comment: Just to be clear, does `git switch -c <new_branch_name>` automatically stage the uncommitted (but staged) changes from before you switched to the new branch, into the new branch?

Comment: @PrithviBoinpally `switch` does not stage anything and changes are _not staged to a branch_. They are staged in your _index_. The index exists independently of any branches. But if you had changes staged already, switching (or creating) branches will not unstage them.

Comment: @knittl ah I was under the impression that each branch had its own index. This makes it make sense.

Answer (score 421):

Alternatively:

1. Save current changes to a temp stash:

   `$ git stash`
2. Create a new branch based on this stash, and switch to the new branch:

   `$ git stash branch <new-branch> stash@{0}`

Tip: use tab key to reduce typing the stash name.

Comment: If the other branch already exists, you can just switch to it with checkout, then `git stash apply`.

Comment: Stash is not safe at all.

Comment: @mayu Care to explain why?

Comment: @wickywills The stash is local to your local repo, so if something happens to your local repo your stash is lost along with it.

Comment: The stash is only used for creating a branch, then the branch can be pushed into remote repository.

Comment: I believe that you don't have to do this. The accepted answer gives a better explanation of the scenario.

Comment: I don't understand the tip "Tip: use tab key to reduce typing the stash name.". Isn't "stash@{0}" the name? I cannot run it successfully.

Comment: Why is this better than the accepted answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/1394804/754997 ?

Comment: I don't understand why this is better then the accepted answer of `git checkout -b <new branch name>`

Comment: @Noitidart this is better if you want to use an existing branch (you can switch to it and use `git stash apply`)

Comment: don't forget to `git add -A` before you `git stash`

Comment: You don't need to `git add -A` before stashing.

Comment: "checkout -b" is good, but I think you should remember "stash apply" for cases when the branch exists... like @Archonic says.

Comment: what does `@{0}` mean?

Comment: @Dennis I believe `@{0}` means that you want the latest commit to a particular branch (e.g. `master@{0}` for example; further reading here: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Revision-Selection )

Comment: Yeah, kinda figured that out as it was quite evident. Thought someone will embrace me with more knowledge just like you did. Thanks :D

Comment: If it isn't working try  $ git stash branch <new-branch> "stash@{0}"

Answer (score 65):

**If you have been making commits** on your main branch while you coded, but you now want to move those commits to a different branch, this is a quick way:

1. Copy your current history onto a new branch, bringing along any uncommitted changes too:

   ```
    git checkout -b <new-feature-branch>
   ```
2. Now force the original "messy" branch to roll back: (without switching to it)

   ```
    git branch -f <previous-branch> <earlier-commit-id>
   ```

   For example:

   ```
    git branch -f master origin/master
   ```

   or if you had made 4 commits:

   ```
    git branch -f master HEAD~4
   ```

***Warning:*** `git branch -f master origin/master` will *reset the tracking information* for that branch.  So if you have configured your `master` branch to push to somewhere other than `origin/master` then that configuration will be lost.

***Warning:*** If you rebase after branching, there is a danger that some commits may be lost, which is [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36463546/99777).  The only way to avoid that is to create a new history using cherry-pick.  That link describes the safest fool-proof method, although less convenient.  (If you have uncommitted changes, you may need to `git stash` at the start and `git stash pop` at the end.)

Comment: This answers a question which is slightly different from what the op asked. I decided to put this answer here because this is where Google brought me when I was searching for an answer. The actual question that deals with this situation [is here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1628563/move-the-most-recent-commits-to-a-new-branch-with-git).

Answer (score 59):

The common scenario is the following: I forgot to create the new branch for the new feature, and was doing all the work in the old feature branch. I have commited all the "old" work to the master branch, and I want my new branch to grow from the "master". I have not made a single commit of my new work.
Here is the branch structure:
"master"->"Old_feature"

```
git stash 
git checkout master
git checkout -b "New_branch"
git stash apply
```

Comment: "git switch -c <new-branch>" cleared the changes of unstaged files (with only new files retains); stash way is better if you're thinking to have exactly all local files back

Comment: That was not my experience -- as others have written above, your local unstaged changes are retained in the new branch. (I must admit that I had to use checkout -b not switch -c, but those two are supposed to be identical)

Answer (score 23):

If you commit it, you could also cherry-pick the single commit ID.  I do this often when I start work in master, and then want to create a local branch before I push up to my origin/.

```
git cherry-pick <commitID>
```

There is alot you can do with cherry-pick, as described [here](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick), but this could be a use-case for you.

Comment: Nicer solution for moving partial changes to a new branch... since you can commit what you want for now, stash all other changes, check out the branch you want to branch from, cherry-pick that commit onto the new branch, go back to the original branch, hard reset back a commit, then do a stash pop, add, commit, and sing hallelujah.

Comment: @Meredith, haha, ya something like that.  This is great, unless you plan your changes ahead...and who does that ;)

Answer (score 9):

**Option 1 (with an existing branch)**

```
git stash (from main/any-branch)
git checkout your-existing-branch
git stash apply
```

**Option 2 (creating a new branch)**

```
git switch -c your-new-branch
```

Answer (score 8):

For those using Visual Studio Community 2022 (and possibly earlier versions) when you have uncommitted changes then create a new branch, you'll see a dialog like this:

[image]

Just select the first option **Bring the changes to '[your-new-branch-name]'** and click **Continue checkout**. The new branch will be created and you can proceed to commit your changes there.

Answer (score 5):

There is actually a really easy way to do this with GitHub Desktop now that I don't believe was a feature before.

All you need to do is switch to the new branch in GitHub Desktop, and it will prompt you to leave your changes on the current branch (which will be stashed), or to bring your changes with you to the new branch. Just choose the second option, to bring the changes to the new branch. You can then commit as usual.

[image: GitHub Desktop]

Answer (score 3):

This may be helpful for all using tools for GIT

**Command**

Switch branch - it will move your changes to new-branch. Then you can commit changes.

```
 $ git checkout -b <new-branch>
```

**TortoiseGIT**

Right-click on your repository and then use TortoiseGit->Switch/Checkout

[image]
[image]

**SourceTree**

Use the "Checkout" button to switch branch. You will see the "checkout" button at the top after clicking on a branch. Changes from the current branch will be applied automatically.  Then you can commit them.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This is the only answer that tells you to use `git stash -k`, which you will need...

**if you already spent an hour with `git add -p`**

and then decided you want to *test* what you added to the index *before* doing the actual commit. In that case do ***not*** use plain `git stash`!

Instead do:

```
git stash -k
```

That keeps the index and removes the rest that is still in the working directory and wasn't added to the index yet. Exactly what you want.

Now you can try to compile/test and commit. I.e.

```
make
git commit -m 'Yay!'
```

Then get back the uncommitted changes with

```
git stash pop
```

If you discover that it does NOT compile however, then making changes and adding those also the index and committing that might confuse `git stash pop`. It isn't that good when it comes to merging. In that case you probably should just commit anyway; thus:

```
make
git commit -m 'Grrrr'
```

Then create a new branch,

```
git switch -c tmpbranch
```

do your work there (changing code, doing testing and more commits)

```
/* blood sweat and tears */
```

Once everything works commit it to the new branch

```
commit -a -m 'Finally!'
```

go back to the old branch and then do the `git stash pop` with the same working directory as where you was when you pushed to the stash.

```
git checkout youknowwhatbranchyouwereonright
git stash pop
```

Commit that too, otherwise you can't merge the tmpbranch.
Then merge the temporary branch that you created.

```
git commit -a -m 'Still working on this.'
git merge tmpbranch
/* fix collisions and commit */
```

Now you can do a rebase to put the 'Still working on this' at the top and squash/fixup the rest into a single comment. For example

```
git rebase -i
```

might give you:

```
pick 540623a Grrr
pick a8589d3 Still working on this.
pick d3b602c Finally
```

Then change that to:

```
reword 540623a Grrr
fixup d3b602c Finally
pick a8589d3 Still working on this.
```

And finally undo the last commit (the 'Still working on this')

```
git reset HEAD~1
```

Answer (score 1):

I used [@Robin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30927991/4149861) answer & listing all that I did,

```
git status                               <-- review/list uncommitted changes
git stash                                <-- stash uncommitted changes
git stash branch <new-branch> stash@{1}  <-- create a branch from stash
git add .                                <-- add local changes
git status                               <-- review the status; ready to commit
git commit -m "local changes ..."        <-- commit the changes
git branch --list                        <-- see list of branches incl the one created above
git status                               <-- nothing to commit, working tree (new-branch) is clean
git checkout <old-branch>                <-- switch back
```

**!**   If the repo has more than one stash, see which one to apply to the new-branch:

```
git stash list  
  stash@{0}: WIP on ...  
  stash@{1}: WIP on ...
```

and inspect the individual stash by,

```
git stash show stash@{1}
```

Or inspect all stashes at once:

```
git stash list -p
```

Answer (score 1):

### 3 Steps to Commit your changes

Suppose you have created a new branch on GitHub with the name **feature-branch**.

[image]

**FETCH**

```
    git pull --all         Pull all remote branches
    git branch -a          List all branches now
```

Checkout and switch to the feature-branch directory. You can simply copy the branch name from the output of branch -a command above

> **`git checkout -b feature-branch`**

**VALIDATE**

Next use the git branch command to see the current branch. It will show feature-branch with * In front of it

```
git branch
```

**COMMIT**

```
git add .   add all files
git commit -m "Rafactore code or use your message"
```

Take update and the push changes on the origin server

```
 git pull origin feature-branch
 git push origin feature-branch
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also create bash aliases to do all of this.

This will create new commands...

- `gitco <branch>` - checks out the specified branch, taking your current changes with you
- `gitconew <new branch name>` - creates a new branch with the specified name (branched off of master) taking your current changes with you

Here are the steps to set up the aliases...

1. Add the following to `~/.bash_profile`

```
gitco ()
{
  git stash && git checkout $1 && git stash apply
}

gitconew ()
{
  git stash && git checkout master && git checkout -b $1 && git stash apply
}
```

2. Run `source ~/.bash_profile` to reload the profile

Now you can run the `gitco` and `gitconew` alias commands.

Here is some more info on bash aliases -> https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-create-bash-aliases/