# git push error due to non-existent large file

Tags: git, github, ipython

I keep getting the same result when trying to push to git:

```
Counting objects: 78, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (67/67), done.
Writing objects: 100% (71/71), 36.29 MiB | 637.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 71 (delta 39), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: error: GH001: Large files detected.
remote: error: Trace: 7e446266168df8617c74b6a319ec4538
remote: error: See http://git.io/iEPt8g for more information.
remote: error: File lecture_2_github_io_numpy_pandas/data/cup98LRN.txt is 111.74 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100 MB
To git@github.com:mas-dse/gbrock.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@github.com:mas-dse/gbrock.git'
```

The thing is, that txt file does not exist any more. I made changes to the ipython notebook to have that text file removed. Saved the notebook. Added the changes to git. Committed the changes. Then try to do a push to git, but it does not want to work.

I can't use the:

```
git rm --cached 'file'
```

Because that file does not exist any more. I have no clue what do. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can't push to GitHub because of large file which I already deleted](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19573031/cant-push-to-github-because-of-large-file-which-i-already-deleted)

Comment: @AndrewC Thank you for the reference. I applied the following code mentioned as one of the answers: 
git filter-branch --index-filter 'git rm -r --cached --ignore-unmatch <file/dir>' HEAD
and I am still getting the same results.

Comment: and HEAD was equal to master when you ran the filter branch?

Comment: @AndrewC thank you for your help. I appreciate you taking the time. GitHub got back to me with this documentation and it worked: https://help.github.com/articles/remove-sensitive-data/

Answer (score 4):

GitHub provided me with this step-by-step documentation and it worked for me: https://help.github.com/articles/remove-sensitive-data/

Basically, needed to do a more thorough cleaning of past commits.