# Items still not letting me push in github after deleting them

Tags: git, github, unreal-engine4, git-lfs

First time asking a question here.

I have been using Github and UE4 for a while now and when I have an asset that exceeds the 100mb limit in Github I add it to LFS. 
However I forgot to add these items (SEE IMAGE BELOW) to LFS and tried to push my branch up. I got this error. No problem I thought, I didn't need these stupidly large assets anyway so I'll just delete them. However after deleting them I got the same error again. I think it might be an issue of Git storing changes additively, so it's likely doing the push in order of add->remove.

How would I fix this? The items are deleted, I simply don't need GIT recognising them anymore?

Thanks

[Example of GITHUB problem when trying to push deleted items that are to large](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wZalh.png)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/19573031/1256452 https://stackoverflow.com/q/26446713/1256452 https://stackoverflow.com/q/26721217/1256452 https://stackoverflow.com/q/19858590/1256452 (and many more)

Comment: (none of those are exact dups, though, because of Git-LFS, so let me know if you want this re-opened)