# Git not allowing commits, complains a file that doesn't exist is too large

Tags: git, github, version-control

I'm trying to commit my changes to a GitHub repository. When I attempt this, I get the following error message:

```
remote: error: GH001: Large files detected. You may want to try Git Large 
File Storage - https://git-lfs.github.com.
remote: error: Trace: 8437e5b9aa45a9a5361b17373e18b518
remote: error: See http://git.io/iEPt8g for more information.
remote: error: File data/voters.csv is 188.80 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB
To https://github.com/belltec/pstat.git
 ! [remote rejected] aww -> aww (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/belltec/pstat.git'
```

The file, data/voters.csv has been removed from the working directory and the recycling bin. I tried to remove it from the Git working tree also, like [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19573031/cant-push-to-github-because-of-large-file-which-i-already-deleted), and I got the following error:

```
C:\Users\awimley\pstat>git filter-branch --index-filter 'git rm -r --cached --ignore-unmatch data/voters.csv' HEAD
Cannot rewrite branches: You have unstaged changes.
```

So I attempted to clear these unstaged changes using tthe command from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52704/how-do-you-discard-unstaged-changes-in-git), which seemed like it worked at first. But now, when I try to commit Git tells me that there are no changes staged for commit. However, if I try to add some, or push to my repo's remote counterpart, I get the original error:

```
Counting objects: 64, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (28/28), done.
Writing objects: 100% (30/30), 11.28 MiB | 1.95 MiB/s, done.
Total 30 (delta 11), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: error: GH001: Large files detected. You may want to try Git Large File Storage - https://git-lfs.github.com.
remote: error: Trace: c2bd5114075f5296f5eb39b75a9ea530
remote: error: See http://git.io/iEPt8g for more information.
remote: error: File data/voters.csv is 188.80 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB
To https://github.com/belltec/pstat.git
 ! [remote rejected] aww -> aww (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/belltec/pstat.git'
```

If I run the filter-branch command again I get the following error:

```
fatal: ambiguous argument 'rm': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'
```

Anyone have a clue what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: After stashing your local changes, there is nothing to commit anymore.  You should try running the `filter-branch` command again at that point.

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to *push* your changes; you've already got them committed locally.  Are you in a state where you have no changes staged?  Do you think you'd be able to do a `git reset --hard aww`, then be able to try your filter-branch once more?

Comment: @SvenMarnach I had already attempted running filter-branch again. I forgot to include this in the original question; it has been updated. Also, you're right, git is not allowing me to push, it is allowing me to commit. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Your second filter-branch output suggests you mistyped something (but since you're on DOS/Windows I can't really be sure; I studiously avoid using Windows).

Comment: I am also a lifetime Linux user, unfortunately my current employer does not allow Linux installs on their office machines. :-/

Comment: Seems like a good reason to quit.  I know, I'm not being helpful. :)

Comment: Its OK, I agree with you for the most part, work is just very difficult to come by nowadays. I never wanted to be a web developer, its just what someone was willing to pay me for, and I do have the technical skills required.