# Git non-cached file being uploaded to Github

Tags: git, github

I m trying to upload my project to github, however it has 1 very large file which is above the github file size limit. I don't want to mess around with the large file storage, I can live with simply not having this file on github.

I have added the file to my `.gitignore` file like this:

```
/Supported Files/AviarySDK/AviarySDK.framework/Versions/A/AviarySDK
```

I have also removed the file from the git cache like this:

```
git rm -r --cached Supported\ Files/AviarySDK/AviarySDK.framework/Versions/A/AviarySDK
```

I then committed the changes. The problem now, if when I try to `git push -u origin master` I get an error back from github:

```
Counting objects: 6746, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (2852/2852), done.
Writing objects: 100% (6746/6746), 139.47 MiB | 724.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 6746 (delta 3804), reused 6597 (delta 3696)
remote: warning: File Supported Files/AviarySDK/AviarySDK.framework/Versions/A/AviarySDK is 94.00 MB; this is larger than GitHub's recommended maximum file size of 50.00 MB
remote: error: GH001: Large files detected. You may want to try Git Large File Storage - https://git-lfs.github.com.
remote: error: Trace: 353c88bf98b546712cb2de8bb086fc17
remote: error: See http://git.io/iEPt8g for more information.
remote: error: File Supported Files/AviarySDK/AviarySDK.framework/Versions/A/AviarySDK is 110.39 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB
To https://github.com/myrepo/MyProject.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/myrepo/MyProject.git'
```

I've tried the solution posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19573031/cant-push-to-github-because-of-large-file-which-i-already-deleted) but as I have uncommitted changes (Which i'm not ready to commit) I get this error:

```
Cannot rewrite branches: You have unstaged changes.
Additionally, your index contains uncommitted changes.
```

Can anyone help me getting this project onto github.

Thanks

Edit 1------

current `git status`:

```
On branch master
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

    new file:   MailingList/MailingListViewController.h
    new file:   MailingList/MailingListViewController.m
    new file:   MailingListViewController.xib

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

    modified:   Operations/RemoteSettings.h
    modified:   Operations/RemoteSettings.m
    modified:   Info.plist
    modified:   MyProject.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj
    modified:   MailingList/MailingListViewController.h
    modified:   MailingList/MailingListViewController.m
    modified:   MailingListViewController.xib
    modified:   MediaViewController.m
    modified:   Supported Files/iRate/iRate.m
    modified:   ViewController.m
```

I'm not ready for these file's to be committed yet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're nearly there, the [solution you linked to](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23657759/212676) is what you need to do (because the large file is already in the git history, so deleting now doesn't help).

Just stash everything before you start:

```
`git stash save -u`
```

(The `-u` flag makes `git stash` include untracked files, i.e. files that you've added to the working tree since the last commit. Normally they would be left alone by `git stash`.)

Then, as per the other answer:

```
git filter-branch --index-filter 'git rm -r --cached --ignore-unmatch Supported\ Files/AviarySDK/AviarySDK.framework/Versions/A/AviarySDK' HEAD
```

Then once you're happy it's gone:

```
git stash pop
```

To restore your working tree changes.

Just as a note of caution, be aware that `filter-branch` **does rewrite history**, so if anyone else has seen this repository they will have trouble merging with the newly filtered version of it.

Comment: Thanks. I can feel i'm getting closer. When I run the `filter-branch` command it rewrites but ends with `WARNING: Ref 'refs/heads/master' is unchanged` and the `git push` still complains of the large file.

Comment: Hey I got it to work. Firstly I didn't escape the white space in the path in my `.gitignore`. After I did that and started the process again, the `filter-branch` command worked and everything got uploaded. Also, I can't thank you enough for the `stash` command. This will come in very handy in future and makes git so much better (I'm a git novice).

Comment: Stash is a godsend. Hey @N3dst4, why `git stash save -u` vs `git stash`? It looks like `save -u`, which I've never used, gives you a new reference point by which you can `git reset --hard` back to. If the intention is to `pop` later, why is this beneficial? [Reference site on `git stash`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash).

Comment: -u is shorthand for --include-untracked

Comment: Edited to explain `git shtash -u`