# Realm framework too large

Tags: ios, github, frameworks, cocoapods, realm

I'm using **Realm** in my iOS project and originally I just dragged and dropped the framework into my project. When I tried to push to GitHub it said it exceeded the **100MB** limit. I deleted that framework from my project and installed **CocoaPods** instead thinking this would solve the issue but it is still saying it is too large.

Any ideas as to what is going on here? Thanks in advance!

This is my exact error:

> File Realm.framework/Realm is 237.27 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't push to GitHub because of large file which I already deleted](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19573031/cant-push-to-github-because-of-large-file-which-i-already-deleted)

Answer (score 0):

I ended up just deleting the cocoapods, creating a new branch and re-writing what I had in the previous branch because it wasn't that much code. This did the trick. I think it had something to do with trying to add the framework in previously by doing drag and drop.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using git large file storage?

https://git-lfs.github.com/

That worked for me.