# git push interrupted while sending big files

Tags: git, github

While I was git push I realized that I was trying to send some very big files ie >1gb- I killed the `git push` and once I `git rm` those big files and git commit once more, and finally `git commit/push` again.

Unfortunately I am always ending up with

```
remote: fatal: pack exceeds maximum allowed size
error: pack-objects died of signal 13
```

although I did

```
git config pack.windowMemory 2g
git config pack.packSizeLimit 2g
```

but this did not work. I also tried to `git revert <commit>`but still the same...It appears like git still tries to finish submitting the big files even though I explicitly removed from the next git action

Comment: hmmm, not sure if the server is in a bad state or your client. Can you make a fresh clone in the meanwhile and see if that fixes the problem?

Comment: I also found this, does it help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19573031/cant-push-to-github-because-of-large-file-which-i-already-deleted

Comment: not really  - I get this `Cannot rewrite branches: You have unstaged changes.`

Comment: can you force it? from what I understand you commited all your work now. Actually you may want to wait on this a bit for a more competent answer.

Comment: indeed tried to force it, but I get a `Cannot rewrite branches: You have unstaged changes.` which I cannot resolve