# Revert a folder deletion on git.

Tags: git, github

I had some huge files in a folder, let's call it `Folder1` and could not commit. I removed the huge files but they remained in the git history, so I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23657759/5016028) on the entire folder....and I lost my folder.

Please, is there a way to revert this huge mess-up?

Comment: Did you force-push your rewritten repository to github after running filter-branch on it? If not, can't you simply re-clone?

Comment: Try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/953481/find-and-restore-a-deleted-file-in-a-git-repository

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do a `git reset --hard origin/master` to get the files from the last push to github.

YOU WILL LOSE EVERY DATA THAT IS NOT COMMITED

That's only working if you already pushed your files to github.

And if you don't commited your files try:

```
git reset
git checkout -- $(git ls-files -d)
```

Comment: Quibix, have you commited the file? And which OS do you have?

Comment: No, sadly the file was not commited. I managed to recover my files from a backup drive. Thanks everyone for your help.

Comment: Qubix, please try the new way in my answer