# Ignored large node_module still tries to push to repo

Tags: git, github, terminal, node-modules, gitignore

For some reason whenever I try to push to my github repo, it stops me saying a file from one of the dependencies I'm using is over 100mb, and it keeps trying to tell me to use git large file storage which I tried, but couldn't figure it out. I have all my node_modules ignored, so I'm confused as to why it still won't let me push. If it matters I'm on a Mac on High Sierra. I have followed many answers to similar other questions saying to use `git rm -r --cached .` then `git add .` and `git commit -m "Fixed untracked files"`, but none of that has fixed the problem. For some reason github is still detecting the large file rather than ignoring it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can't push to GitHub because of large file which I already deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19573031/cant-push-to-github-because-of-large-file-which-i-already-deleted)

Comment: Already saw that and bunch of other like it and none of it worked. Plus I'm not deleting the file because it is something relating to a node package I'm using. I'm simply having github ignore that file so that it isn't pushed to my repo, but for some reason github isn't ignoring it.