# Removing deleted file from Git commit not working

Tags: xcode, git, github, cocoapods

I forgot to `.gitignore` my `Pods/` directory, and I accidentally checked in and committed a file larger than 100MB so I can't push to github. Even after removing the pods all together with `pod update`, manually deleting the directory causing the issue, and running `git rm --cached -r Pods/` to remove all Pods from the commit, it still gives me the same error every time I try to push:

```
remote: error: File Pods/GoogleMobileVision/TextDetector/Frameworks/TextDetector.framework/TextDetector is 267.62 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have one or more *existing commits* that contain the large file(s).

When you run `git push`, you don't send *files* to GitHub.  You send *commits*.

If you have deleted the huge files and committed again, you now have at least two new commits for GitHub: one that has the huge files, followed by a second one that doesn't have them.  What you want is to have is fewer and/or different commits, none of which have the huge files in them.

See [Can't push to GitHub because of large file which I already deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19573031/1256452) for more about cleaning up after this.

Answer (score -1):

First, remove the `Pods` directory and commit that:

```
rm -rf Pods
git add .
git commit -m "Remove Pods/ directory"
```

Then add `Pods/` to your `.gitignore` and commit that:

```
git add .
git commit -m "Add Pods/ directory to .gitignore"
```

Now you should be able to run `pod install`/`pod update` and push to GitHub without any issues.

Comment: I'm still getting the same error even after doing that, is that because I had previously committed all of those Pods?