# git filter-branch mistake

Tags: git, github

I'm very new and having a hard time. I tried to implement the solution linked below, but it didn't fix my problem and seems to have really wrecked my repo. I'm not even sure how to describe it, but I'll try.

1. I was having trouble pushing to git because of large files.
2. I installed git lfs
3. The original repo (from a class I'm in) didn't seem set up to receive git lfs configurations, so I cloned a new repo from my original
4. The problem continued, but I kept making commits without pushing, and eventually manually deleted the file
5. I still couldn't push, so I looked up this solution: [Can't push to GitHub because of large file which I already deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19573031/cant-push-to-github-because-of-large-file-which-i-already-deleted). I saw too late that the first solution was a seriously destructive process.
6. After this it gets really messy with different numbers of commits between my two repos and "tip of current branch behind its remote counterpart"
7. It seems like I've really destroyed my repo. I can't open my older work, and I can't push my newer work. What can I do? I've been working on this project for a few weeks and I would really hate to lose it.

Let me know if I can share more detail. Thanks for your help!

Comment: did you do any real work after getting stuck into not being able to push the large file?

Comment: `git` has a big undo stack : `git reflog`. Spot the important commits in there, and mark them with a branch -- e.g : `git branch back/last-valid-state [sha1]`. You will feel safer once you know your work is still there, and will have all the leisure to inspect your current content.

Comment: From what you write I really wonder, whether why you are the only one with such a big file.