# Can not push backup to GitHub due to too large files

Tags: github, commit, git-rewrite-history

I am aware that this issue has several related issues, but I have a slightly backward problem, where there already is a commit history to preserve.

I have a project repo I worked on last year together with several other people. I have successfully pushed the changes to this repo(education license for Bitbucket repo). I have attempted to make a backup of this repo to my private Github since the Edu repo will be wiped eventually. Some of the files are larger than Githubs file limit, so I have packaged these files into segmented packages that fit within Githubs filesize limit. The problem is that there is still a history of these larger files, and pushing is aborted once these files are getting processed.

Is there any way to only change the history of these files for my backup version, and not mangle the original version history? Essentially not processing the big files on the Github commit history, and just skip straight to the segmented packages version.

The most related issue I've managed to find is this one [Can't push to GitHub because of large file which I already deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19573031/cant-push-to-github-because-of-large-file-which-i-already-deleted)
which mentions that you should not run the command without understanding the consequences (which I think it does, and that would be changing the history).