# failed to push some refs || Large files detected

Tags: git, github, cocoapods, swift-package-manager

I'm working on a Swift project and I was using Cocoapods on this project then one advised me to transfer to Swift Package Manager because it is easy to use and because it showed me a lot of warnings.
so I used this command to uninstall Cocoapods:
`pod deintegrate  pod cache clean --all`  
Then while I was trying to push my files to my repository, the push failed for some large files.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jermq.jpg)

I don't know it and I think it's from Cocoapods and I wasn't delete it and I don't know how to do it.

Comment: This question has been answered a big number of times. Search on stackoverflow. For example: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23657759/717372