# Can't push to GitHub because of a missing object

Tags: git, github, git-push, git-pull

I was having a problem with large files already deleted, so I use `git filter-repo` to solve this problem as I see in [Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19573031/cant-push-to-github-because-of-large-file-which-i-already-deleted) when I finished following the steps I was surprised that the git don't have a URL remote, I made sure by running `git remote -v` and it gave me an empty message so I add it again by `git remote add <repository_url>` and made sure that it connected and it gives me an error message below

`ref "main":: missing object: 919434a6254f0e9651f402737811be6634a03e9c  error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/'`

when I searched a little bit I understand that the error message I received indicated that there is a missing object in the Git history, so I tried to run `git pull origin main` but it still give me the same error.