Having Problem in pushing large files in git
There is an error coming everytime i push my file on github.
I tried changing the version of https from 2 to 1.1 ,
I have also tried to track files using git lf,
I have also added these files to the .gitignore folder,
I have also changed from https to ssh for sending files to github,
I have also tried the solution mentioned at : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19573031/cant-push-to-github-because-of-large-file-which-i-already-deleted
Still i get this error :
Enumerating objects: 76367, done.
Counting objects: 100% (76367/76367), done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (49370/49370), done.
Writing objects: 100% (76366/76366), 1.17 GiB | 2.12 MiB/s, done.
Total 76366 (delta 26282), reused 76359 (delta 26279), pack-reused 0
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (26282/26282), done.
remote: warning: File venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/clang/native/libclang.so is 60.75 MB; this is larger than GitHub's recommended maximum file size of 50.00 MB
remote: error: Trace: 053073245363bb6b48b2fc13e4980575370c445830e912ee42685110f91e1b2a
remote: error: See https://gh.io/lfs for more information.
remote: error: File image_features_embedding.pkl is 348.68 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB
remote: error: File venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/tensorflow/libtensorflow_framework.so.2 is 133.44 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB
remote: error: File venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/tensorflow/libtensorflow_cc.so.2 is 988.72 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB
remote: error: GH001: Large files detected. You may want to try Git Large File Storage - https://git-lfs.github.com.
To github.com:Vedicavg/Fashion-recommender.git
 ! [remote rejected]     main -> main (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'github.com:Vedicavg/Fashion-recommender.git'


What should i do now? How can i push my repository to github!

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+remove+large+file+history

My advice is to remove the entire venv directory. Bear in mind you need to remove it from all commits, not from the current directory, not from the last commit — from all commits.
