# Git repo size increased post BFG Repo Cleaner use

Tags: git, github, git-rewrite-history, bfg-repo-cleaner

I have cleaned my repo with [BFG Repo Cleaner](https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/)

```
$ git clone --mirror ssh://git@example.com/some-big-repo.git
$ java -jar bfg-1.12.8.jar --strip-blobs-bigger-than 100M some-big-repo.git
```

Output from above command:

```
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.

Using repo : some-big-repo.git

Scanning packfile for large blobs: 1064306
Scanning packfile for large blobs completed in 6,655 ms.
Found 17 blob ids for large blobs - biggest=548483051 smallest=154402960
Total size (unpacked)=6732468925
Found 13643 objects to protect
Found 175 tag-pointing refs : refs/tags/alpha_7_0_0_27, refs/tags/alpha_7_0_0_28, refs/tags/alpha_7_0_0_29, ...
Found 1886 commit-pointing refs : HEAD, refs/heads/CLI-PS-Command-Shows-Tag-And-Branch, refs/heads/IBIS-15065-ibis70, ...

Protected commits
-----------------

These are your protected commits, and so their contents will NOT be altered:

 * commit 5ebfab47 (protected by 'HEAD') - contains 1 dirty file : 
    - system-profiles-backup.zip (147.3 MB)

WARNING: The dirty content above may be removed from other commits, but as
the *protected* commits still use it, it will STILL exist in your repository.

Details of protected dirty content have been recorded here :

some-big-repo.git.bfg-report/2015-12-16/16-30-47/protected-dirt/

If you *really* want this content gone, make a manual commit that removes it,
and then run the BFG on a fresh copy of your repo.


Cleaning
--------

Found 87529 commits
Cleaning commits:       100% (87529/87529)
Cleaning commits completed in 8,549 ms.

Updating 300 Refs
-----------------

    Ref                                                                  Before     After   
    ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    refs/heads/CLI-PS-Command-Shows-Tag-And-Branch                     | d80c38e9 | abea37b6
    refs/heads/IBIS-15065-ibis70                                       | e7072a57 | 5fa674fa
    refs/heads/IBIS-16015                                              | 91e27129 | b7d724e9
    refs/heads/IBIS-16015_SUP20773                                     | db6ab9ff | 0e3e4bea
    refs/heads/IBIS-17123                                              | 6240c520 | c5c80835
    refs/heads/IBIS-17763                                              | fc30c283 | 658a4e1a
    refs/heads/IBIS-18691_Suspended_Entries_disappear_while_migration  | d9a2664e | d1d94242
    refs/heads/IBIS-18800_PortalRelaseAfterFix                         | 6bc61c8d | 74667b55
    refs/heads/IBIS-19245                                              | a5b22b93 | 6811dabd
    refs/heads/IBIS-19367_70                                           | c9b55fef | 7662bb67
    refs/heads/IBIS-19409_Merge_71                                     | 39c9ce35 | 78e3b4d4
    refs/heads/IBIS-19409_Remove_Retry_Timeout_Validation              | 08f0fbe4 | a6261048
    refs/heads/IBIS-19686-sessionFixationValve-is61                    | bf6a76d9 | 08785e1d
    refs/heads/IBIS-20041-ibis61                                       | a5e0bd71 | cb907ae5
    refs/heads/IBIS-20128                                              | 45f4d8d6 | e7502f69
    ...

Updating references:    100% (300/300)
...Ref update completed in 80 ms.

Commit Tree-Dirt History
------------------------

    Earliest                                              Latest
    |                                                          |
    .........................................Dm...DDDDDDDDDDDDDD

    D = dirty commits (file tree fixed)
    m = modified commits (commit message or parents changed)
    . = clean commits (no changes to file tree)

                            Before     After   
    -------------------------------------------
    First modified commit | 8733298e | 6df4eda8
    Last dirty commit     | fa17594e | 64ad5e9c

Deleted files
-------------

    Filename                                 Git id                                       
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    SystemBackupArchiveAS461.zip           | 22107431 (461.6 MB)                          
    SystemBackupArchiveAS470.zip           | 9171cef4 (334.1 MB)                          
    SystemBackupArchiveAS471.zip           | c3cfc352 (284.7 MB)                          
    SystemBackupArchiveTasksWaitings61.zip | 7a07cebc (523.1 MB)                          
    SystemBackupArchiveTasksWaitings70.zip | 9dde5c99 (341.9 MB)                          
    SystemBackupArchiveTasksWaitings71.zip | d6252b6d (306.4 MB)                          
    backup61DiscontinuedPlugin.zip         | 7f44976a (461.9 MB)                          
    backup61WithUserSuspend.zip            | 40b949e4 (453.1 MB)                          
    backupXSLTConverter61.zip              | 5c4dd7c9 (326.0 MB), c09da1e4 (467.1 MB)     
    distribution-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar        | 10bc3f1c (159.3 MB)                          
    migration61to70backup.zip              | af5d924c (490.5 MB), c595cfd9 (467.2 MB), ...
    system-profiles-backup.zip             | 373b5a98 (147.3 MB)                          


In total, 43855 object ids were changed. Full details are logged here:

    some-big-repo.git.bfg-report/2015-12-16/16-30-47

BFG run is complete! When ready, run: git reflog expire --expire=now --all && git gc --prune=now --aggressive


Has the BFG saved you time?  Support the BFG on BountySource:  https://j.mp/fund-bfg

$ cd some-big-repo.git
$ git reflog expire --expire=now --all && git gc --prune=now --aggressive
```

I can see that my local repo has shrunk from 6.4G to 1.4G. Great. I try a push now

```
$ git push
```

git push didn't work gave me this error message:

```
Counting objects: 218648, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (81662/81662), done.
Writing objects: 100% (215818/215818), 666.89 MiB | 1.07 MiB/s, done.
Total 215818 (delta 119117), reused 210562 (delta 115381)
remote: Communication breakdown with Stash.
To ssh://git@example.com/some-big-repo.git


! [remote rejected] CLI-PS-Command-Shows-Tag-And-Branch -> CLI-PS-Command-Shows-Tag-And-Branch (pre-receive hook declined)


! [remote rejected] CUC-112 -> CUC-112 (pre-receive hook declined)

...

! [remote rejected] rc_7_0_0_9 -> rc_7_0_0_9 (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'ssh://git@example.com/some-big-repo.git'
```

Later I did a fresh clone of my repo and this time to my surprise now the repo shows bigger size 7.4G. I am really not sure what went on here and need inputs on rectifying stuffs.

Comment: There is a pre-receive hook on the remote that prevented you from pushing your modified history there.

Comment: I confirm that there are no server side or even client side hooks set for the repo. Even if the push failed why is my repo size increased?

Comment: There is 100% sure a pre-receive hook on the remote that you are trying to push to, see the message: `! [remote rejected] CUC-112 -> CUC-112 (pre-receive hook declined)` - as for the size increasing, I don't have an answer. Perhaps some of the branches were pushed succesfully?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Git push error pre-receive hook declined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28318599/git-push-error-pre-receive-hook-declined)