# Remote GitLab API is not accessible

Tags: git, gitlab, githooks, gitlab-omnibus

Yesterday I installed GitLab Community Edition on my server. Installation went fine, but this error occurs when we push data or files to the GitLab server:

```
Password for 'http://naman550.dx@gmail.com@112.196.23.228': 
Counting objects: 6, done.
Delta compression using up to 2 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (2/2), done.
Writing objects: 100% (6/6), 431 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 6 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: GitLab: API is not accessible
To http://112.196.23.228/Naman/mt-test.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'http://112.196.23.228/Naman/mt-test.git'
```

Comment: Have you set the `external_url` in your `gitlab.rb`?

Comment: yes,i have set external_url in my gitlab.rb file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Git push error pre-receive hook declined](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28318599/git-push-error-pre-receive-hook-declined)

Answer (score 0):

Check to make sure that branch master is not protected. To my understanding the master branch is protected by default. [Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PBKAb.png)

You can unprotect/protect branches in the project settings.

You can also check that the gitlab_url is set correctly in the gitlab-shell config located at `/opt/gitlab/embedded/service/gitlab-shell/config.yml`. Make sure you run `sudo gitlab-ctl restart` after editing this file.