# Heroku deploy stucks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku

I've push everything to github master branch and currently wanna deploy it to heroku, but got this error.

```
➜  xxxx git:(master) ✗ git push heroku master                                                                                                                            
Counting objects: 18, done.                 
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.    
Compressing objects: 100% (16/16), done.    
Writing objects: 100% (18/18), 2.34 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.                               
Total 18 (delta 12), reused 0 (delta 0)     
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote:  !   
remote:  !   Build timed out while waiting to start.
remote:  !   
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !       Push rejected to xxxxxx-xxxxx.
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxx.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/xxxxx-xxxx-xxx.git'
```

Comment: Seems to me, something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28318599/git-push-error-pre-receive-hook-declined it will depend on what you use and are trying to do

Comment: Can you please post Heroku logs?

Answer (score 0):

Try a `git pull` first - can sometimes mean there are commits that you are going to lose when pushing

Comment: That was a trouble on heroku side