# git: 'lfs' is not a git command unclear

Tags: git, github

Every time I enter in my command window

```
git lfs install
```

the message I get is `git: 'lfs' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.`

I tried looking up for a solution, but none of the answers were clear. Can someone explain clear how to fix this?

Comment: on Ubuntu I had forgot to complete the install... `sudo apt-get install git-lfs` see: https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/wiki/Installation

Answer (score 319):

It looks like you haven't downloaded git-lfs on your machine, so `git lfs install` isn't a registered command by git.

Install git-lfs as outlined below:

---

### 1. Pre-Requisites

- git-lfs requires [git](https://git-scm.com/) version 1.8.3.1 or later. You can check the version you have by running `git --version`, and update if required.
- If you are installing on macOS, make sure you have [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/) installed.

### 2. Download

Download git-lfs by following the steps based on your operating system.

**Debian / Ubuntu**

```
$ curl -s https://packagecloud.io/install/repositories/github/git-lfs/script.deb.sh | sudo bash
$ sudo apt-get install git-lfs
```

**MacOS (Using Homebrew)**

```
$ brew update
$ brew install git-lfs
```

**Windows**

Download and run the latest [windows installer](https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/releases).

### 3. Install

Finally, run `git-lfs install` to install `git-lfs` on your system.
You can always run `git-lfs uninstall` to uninstall.

---

*More detailed information (such as for installation on other platforms) can be found on git-lfs's [installation page](https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/wiki/Installation).*

Comment: I did install the git lfs, but it is still saying that message

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: we still have some Windows XP here and installer doesnt work there. adding git-lfs to PATH didn't help either

Comment: update to this: you need to install a (old) proper version for windows XP 32 bit. I contacted developers and the last one supporting this OS is git-lfs-windows-v2.5.0

Comment: I was going through https://git-lfs.github.com/ & surprised why the `sudo apt-get install git-lfs` command was not there! Anyway, thank you so much for the answer!

Comment: Why does the [quick install page on packagecloud](https://packagecloud.io/github/git-lfs/install) just have the `curl` command, but not the `sudo apt-get install git-lfs` command, which is quite important.

Answer (score 36):

You can't directly use

```sh
git lfs install
```

Instead of that, you can use these commands to download and install
(you have to download it before installing).

```
sudo apt-get install git-lfs
git-lfs install
```

Comment: Or `sudo pacman -Suy git-lfs`

Answer (score 11):

Here is a solution for people installing git-lfs on a system without "sudo".
Basically, it is to download the latest tarball (from [here](https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/releases)), uncompress it, add it to your environment PATH, and install it to git. It worked for me, at least.

```bash
wget https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/releases/download/v3.2.0/git-lfs-linux-amd64-v3.2.0.tar.gz
tar -xzf git-lfs-linux-amd64-v3.2.0.tar.gz
PATH=$PATH:/export/fs04/a12/rhuang/git-lfs-3.2.0/
git lfs install
git lfs version
```

Comment: Thanks! Been looking for the local install solution for a while! It works for me!

Comment: And don't forget to cd into the untarred folder and run `install.sh` (may need to modify the   `prefix` to a non-system path) -- https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs#from-binary

Comment: @YiboYang what does modify the prefix to a non-system path means here

Answer (score 8):

In addition to "arct" answer, if you have an M1 Silicone Mac, you must use the following to install it using homebrew

```
arch -arm64 brew install git-lfs
```

Answer (score 5):

none of those pages specify how to install. They just say download and install. I'm running in circles here. Quite frustrating. Download and install, but no mention in getting started as to HOW to install.

"Download and install the Git command line extension. Once downloaded and installed, set up Git LFS for your user account by running: git lfs install"

Sure I can download, but nothing I'm attempting will install. Brew won't recognize the commands, nor will mac port. cd to the location of the folder. Attempt again. Nothing. Not even when running git-lfs from the download and reading those directions is there any clarity. "To get started with Git LFS, the following commands can be used..." They don't work. Can't enter commands in the git-lfs window, nor are they recognized in bash.

Thanks.

---

Had to go here to find an answer to that assumed process:

https://www.addictivetips.com/mac-os/run-shell-sh-script-on-macos/

How to run a Shell or .sh script on macOS

cd ~/Downloads/git-lfs-darwin-amd64-v2.13.2

chmod +x install.sh

sh install.sh

Comment: You are a life saver! tnx mate

Answer (score 4):

LFS is not part of Git, it needs to be installed separately. See [the Git LFS site](https://git-lfs.github.com). Following the 'Getting Started' instructions for your platform should resolve the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Note if you are on Apple Silicon (eg M1), and using homebrew installed in the default way, homebrew will be installed at `/opt/homebrew`. (See https://docs.brew.sh/Installation).

This path (`/opt/homebrew`) is not part of the default `PATH` env variable. Looks like this causes issues in git recognizing lfs in subsequent `git lfs ...` commands.

Fix is to include it in the path: `export PATH=$PATH:/opt/homebrew/bin`. And then do the `git lfs ...` operations.

Answer (score 1):

On Arch Linux, `sudo pacman -S git-lfs`

Answer (score 0):

I had this when building with Atlassian Bamboo and the resolution was to build first time without lfs checked (advanced options). After that you can go back and select lfs and it fetches fine from git without the lfs error.

Answer (score 0):

use git bash cmd window, also make sure you've downloaded and installed git lfs

my answer is on the assumption that you are probably using Windows OS, so using the other given solutions may not work, so this is for if you are on windows

Comment: Thank you for your interest in contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This question already has quite a few answers—including one that has been extensively validated by the community. Are you certain your approach hasn’t been given previously? **If so, it would be useful to explain how your approach is different, under what circumstances your approach might be preferred, and/or why you think the previous answers aren’t sufficient.** Can you kindly [edit] your answer to offer an explanation?