# Unable to install git lfs

Tags: git, git-lfs

First tried

```
brew install git-lfs
git lfs install
```

and the initial install works but then I get "lfs command not found".
Read I needed to try:

```
sudo apt install git-lfs
```

"The operation couldn’t be completed. Unable to locate a Java Runtime that supports apt."
Installed JRE, JDK. Still getting same message.

I tried everything here: [git: 'lfs' is not a git command unclear](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48734119/git-lfs-is-not-a-git-command-unclear)
and read everything I could find on SO about this.

I added C:\Program Files\Git\bin to the system path. That didn't do anything.

I have an intel silicon mac.

Comment: `C:\Program Files\Git\bin` is a Windows-style path. Macs (of any sort) do not use Windows-style paths: path name slashes are normal (forward) slashes, not the backwards ones. Meanwhile `apt` is for Linux, not macOS.

Answer (score 0):

had to go into the file where I had downloaded it:

```
cd ~/Downloads/git-lfs-3.2.0
```

(may not be 3.2.0 for you)

then ran

```
./install.sh
```