# Not able to Push React code in Github master

Tags: reactjs, github

Not able to Push React code in Github master due to larger size.

```
git push -u origin master                                                                      
Enumerating objects: 41025, done.
Counting objects: 100% (41025/41025), done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (25146/25146), done.
Writing objects: 100% (41025/41025), 190.44 MiB | 5.20 MiB/s, done.
Total 41025 (delta 14626), reused 41025 (delta 14626), pack-reused 0
remote: Resolving deltas: 100% (14626/14626), done.
remote: warning: File node_modules/.cache/default-development/20.pack is 54.54 MB; this is larger than GitHub's recommended maximum file size of 50.00 MB
remote: warning: File node_modules/.cache/default-development/101.pack is 79.78 MB; this is larger than GitHub's recommended maximum file size of 50.00 MB
remote: error: Trace: 8dfc24e220167542a79ef96d0c9f68e0381fecd6e731ab98b3ad1c16716d2e46
remote: error: See http://git.io/iEPt8g for more information.
remote: error: File node_modules/.cache/default-development/0.pack is 164.76 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB
remote: error: File node_modules/.cache/default-development/65.pack is 164.10 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB
remote: error: GH001: Large files detected. You may want to try Git Large File Storage - https://git-lfs.github.com.
To https://github.com/u121/DemoPage.git
 ! [remote rejected]   master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/u121/DemoPage.git'
```

Getting this error when i use git push -u origin master  in app

Comment: exclude `node_modules` using [`.gitignore `](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore)

Answer (score 1):

`File node_modules/.cache/default-development/0.pack is 164.76 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB`.

In general, you don't want to push the node modules folder, but rather only push your `package.json` / `package-lock.json` and use `npm install` to download your dependencies.

Answer (score 1):

Add node_modules in .gitignore file. It will ignore node modules when you commit your code.

Comment: please be more precise, cite the added line to the .gitignore file

Answer (score 0):

On top of the above answer, I see your repo doesn't have `master` on Github. Just double-check if this was intentional or your repo has protection that prevents you from pushing to `master`

[Git push error pre-receive hook declined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28318599/git-push-error-pre-receive-hook-declined)

NB: I don't have access to comment.