# Heroku build app failed for react app and throw an errors

Tags: reactjs, git, heroku, deployment, heroku-cli

I wanna deploy my react app to heroku and this is my first time .
when I run `git push heroku master` code in cmd I get this code(errors) :

```
λ git push heroku master
Total 0 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote:
remote: -----> Building on the Heroku-20 stack
remote: -----> Determining which buildpack to use for this app
remote: -----> Node.js app detected
remote:
remote: -----> Creating runtime environment
remote:
remote:        NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
remote:        NODE_VERBOSE=false
remote:        NODE_ENV=production
remote:        NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true
remote:
remote: -----> Installing binaries
remote:        engines.node (package.json):  8.11.1
remote:        engines.npm (package.json):   unspecified (use default)
remote:
remote:        Resolving node version 8.11.1...
remote:        Downloading and installing node 8.11.1...
remote:        Using default npm version: 5.6.0
remote:
remote: -----> Installing dependencies
remote:        Installing node modules (package.json + package-lock)
remote:        npm ERR! Error while executing:
remote:        npm ERR! /usr/bin/git ls-remote -h -t ssh://git@github.com/ethereumjs/ethereumjs-abi.git
remote:        npm ERR!
remote:        npm ERR! Host key verification failed.
remote:        npm ERR! fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
remote:        npm ERR!
remote:        npm ERR! Please make sure you have the correct access rights
remote:        npm ERR! and the repository exists.
remote:        npm ERR!
remote:        npm ERR! exited with error code: 128
remote:
remote:        npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
remote:        npm ERR!     /tmp/npmcache.yrELD/_logs/2022-08-20T01_18_56_765Z-debug.log
remote:
remote: -----> Build failed
remote:
remote:        We're sorry this build is failing! You can troubleshoot common issues here:
remote:        https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/troubleshooting-node-deploys
remote:
remote:        If you're stuck, please submit a ticket so we can help:
remote:        https://help.heroku.com/
remote:
remote:        Love,
remote:        Heroku
remote:
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app.
remote:
remote:  !     Push failed
remote:  !
remote:  ! ## Warning - The same version of this code has already been built: 86c01aad33db8c46b5f43eea779e18a065ddeba8
remote:  !
remote:  ! We have detected that you have triggered a build from source code with version 86c01aad33db8c46b5f43eea779e18a065ddeba8
remote:  ! at least twice. One common cause of this behavior is attempting to deploy code from a different branch.
remote:  !
remote:  ! If you are developing on a branch and deploying via git you must run:
remote:  !
remote:  !     git push heroku <branchname>:main
remote:  !
remote:  ! This article goes into details on the behavior:
remote:  !   https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/duplicate-build-version
remote:
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote:
remote: !       Push rejected to dapp-token-exchange-alisat.
remote:
To https://git.heroku.com/dapp-token-exchange-alisat.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/dapp-token-exchange-alisat.git'
```

I try to solve issues with following solutions :

- made git repository public
- add new branch and test the push with that
- remove packge-lock.json

None of it worked :(

The source code is here : https://github.com/AliSat81/Solidity---Web3.git

Hope you guys can help me out ,
Thanks in advance .

Comment: Refer..  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28318599/git-push-error-pre-receive-hook-declined

Comment: The failure is saying that `ssh://git@github.com/ethereumjs/ethereumjs-abi.git` (**not** `AliSat81/Solid...`) is inaccessible. What's not clear is why this should be the case, if you have (well, if Heroku has) a valid ssh login on GitHub, but it would make sense to use the https form of the URL so that Heroku does not *need* a valid ssh login here.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+Host+key+verification+failed