# Heroku deploy getting stuck [NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error]

Tags: php, heroku

I have a problems: I tried to deploy a php website on heroku, but got error.

`NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error` 
I not sure what I have to do....

```
$ git push heroku master
Counting objects: 9, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (9/9), done.
Writing objects: 100% (9/9), 53.89 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 9 (delta 7), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: -----> Node.js app detected
remote: 
remote: -----> Creating runtime environment
remote:        
remote:        NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
remote:        NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=true
remote:        NODE_VERBOSE=false
remote:        NODE_ENV=production
remote:        NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true
remote: 
remote: -----> Installing binaries
remote:        engines.node (package.json):  unspecified
remote:        engines.npm (package.json):   unspecified (use default)
remote:        
remote:        Resolving node version 6.x...
remote:        Downloading and installing node 6.11.2...
remote:        Using default npm version: 3.10.10
remote: 
remote: -----> Restoring cache
remote:        Loading 2 from cacheDirectories (default):
remote:        - node_modules
remote:        - bower_components (not cached - skipping)
remote: 
remote: -----> Building dependencies
remote:        Installing node modules (package.json)
remote: 
remote: -----> Caching build
remote:        Clearing previous node cache
remote:        Saving 2 cacheDirectories (default):
remote:        - node_modules
remote:        - bower_components (nothing to cache)
remote: 
remote: -----> Build succeeded!
remote: -----> App not compatible with buildpack: https://codon-        buildpacks.s3.amazonaws.com/buildpacks/heroku/php.tgz
remote:        More info:                 
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks#detection-        failure
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !    Push rejected to tamsan-storage.
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/tamsan-storage.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/hoge.git'
```

Comment: As the errormessage `To https://git.heroku.com/tamsan-storage.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/hoge.git'
` quite clearly states there is a problem with pushing to the github repository.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Git error when trying to push -- pre-receive hook declined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7986139/git-error-when-trying-to-push-pre-receive-hook-declined)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
heroku buildpacks:clear
```

it will let Heroku auto-detect your [buildpacks](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/buildpacks) if its possible/applicable

another option is to select it from Heroku website in your application settings page

[image]

[image]

if its not working let us know what type of application you are trying to deploy.