# 'git push heroku master' push fails

Tags: reactjs, heroku

I am trying to push my react website to Heroku, I have done all the prior steps needed but I keep getting the same error no matter what I try. When I try to do `git push heroku master` I get the error:

```
! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined) error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/antique-ecommerce-ah.git'
```

I have tried deleting and remaking the git repository, adding the right buildpacks, and deleting and reinstalling node modules.

[image: This photo] is the point in the process where it fails.

or here is the copy and paste:

> remote:  [webpack.Progress] 66% building 467/470 modules 3 active
>   /tmp/build_19ad47ba4defadb01c1c1c8147eb87c6/node_modules/core-js/modules/_math-expm1.js
>   remote:  [webpack.Progress] 66% building 468/470 modules 2 active
>   /tmp/build_19ad47ba4defadb01c1c1c8147eb87c6/node_modules/core-js/modules/_math-expm1.js
>   remote:  [webpack.Progress] 66% building 469/470 modules 1 active
>   /tmp/build_19ad47ba4defadb01c1c1c8147eb87c6/node_modules/css-loader/index.js??ref--7-2!/tmp/build_19ad47ba4defadb01c1c1c8147eb87c6/node_modules/postcss-loader/lib/index.js??ref--7-3!/tmp/build_19ad47ba4defadb01c1c1c8147eb87c6/node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--7-4!/tmp/build_19ad47ba4defadb01c1c1c8147eb87c6/src/style/main.scss
>   remote:  [webpack.Progress] 70% building 469/470 modules 1 active
>   /tmp/build_19ad47ba4defadb01c1c1c8147eb87c6/node_modules/css-loader/index.js??ref--7-2!/tmp/build_19ad47ba4defadb01c1c1c8147eb87c6/node_modules/postcss-loader/lib/index.js??ref--7-3!/tmp/build_19ad47ba4defadb01c1c1c8147eb87c6/node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--7-4!/tmp/build_19ad47ba4defadb01c1c1c8147eb87c6/src/style/main.scss
>   remote:  [webpack.Progress] 70% building 470/470 modules 0 active 
>   remote: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE remote: npm ERR! errno 1 remote: npm
>   ERR! react-redux-router@1.0.0 build: `cross-env NODE_ENV=production
>   webpack --config webpack/prod.config.js --progress
>   --display-error-details --color` remote: npm ERR! Exit status 1 remote: npm ERR! remote: npm ERR! Failed at the
>   react-redux-router@1.0.0 build script. remote: npm ERR! This is
>   probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging
>   output above. remote:  remote: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can
>   be found in: remote: npm ERR!
>   /tmp/npmcache.1fuiH/_logs/2019-12-17T01_30_01_262Z-debug.log remote:
>   npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE remote: npm ERR! errno 1 remote: npm ERR!
>   react-redux-router@1.0.0 heroku-postbuild: `npm run build` remote: npm
>   ERR! Exit status 1 remote: npm ERR! remote: npm ERR! Failed at the
>   react-redux-router@1.0.0 heroku-postbuild script. remote: npm ERR!
>   This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional
>   logging output above. remote: remote: npm ERR! A complete log of this
>   run can be found in: remote: npm ERR!
>   /tmp/npmcache.1fuiH/_logs/2019-12-17T01_30_01_280Z-debug.log remote: 
>   remote: -----> Build failed

Comment: You gave us the end of the stack trace, please give us the begining too.

Comment: I will add it to the main question, whats the best way to add it? Its hundreds of lines long. Im new to this.

Comment: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7986139/git-error-when-trying-to-push-pre-receive-hook-declined] might help

Comment: will check it thanks!