# "remote: Gogs: Internal error" error while pushing

Tags: linux, git, ubuntu, gogs

I just installed Gogs at my windows environment and when tried to push, I'm getting this error. I checked all the solutions on the internet, I can't find any.
One of the solutions I tried is changing the path of the gog.db file from relative to absolute but it didn't work for me. Help me out.

I'm using ubuntu in windows by the way.

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7988885/2303202

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/gogs/gogs/issues/4625) you can find the logs location to investigate further

Comment: Nothing is working.

Answer (score 0):

Just recreate project with templates file. You don`t have any branch.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).