# When pushing for the first time to Gitlab get ! [remote rejected] development -> development (pre-receive hook declined)

Tags: git, gitlab

I'm trying to start working with GitLab for the first time. I created a new repo locally and tried to push that to GitLab. What I get is:

```
! [remote rejected] development -> development (pre-receive hook declined)
```

I know that by default master/main branch is protected so I (with a `developer` role) can't push there. That's why I from the even beginning created the `developer` branch. I even do not have the main branch locally at all, here is `git branch` output:

```
* development
```

So I'm definitely not trying to push into the main. But I still get this error. Could you please provide any ideas on how I should handle that?

Comment: What command did you use to push to your repo? Also, this Question might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7986139/git-error-when-trying-to-push-pre-receive-hook-declined

Comment: @MauriceNino git push --set-upstream origin development

Comment: Hm weird, dont know too much about GitLab to be honest, but you could always just `git clone` the repo, and then make your changes (so just switch branch, copy the files and then push)

Comment: "pre-receive hook declined" means they (GitLab) told you "no". Ideally, *before* they tell you "no, I won't do that", they should tell you *why* they won't do that. But if they won't tell you why, you'll have to ask them (GitLab) more directly / in-person, and see if you can get an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, the thing was in permissions. As I understand - if your role is `developer` and repo is empty (that means no `main/master` branch), than yau have no ability to up in it an initial commit as it means that you also push `main/master` there. So if you face this problem - ask somebody who maintain repo to increase your permissions temporarily for the time of first push

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the remote development branch has commits that you don't have, which would make the push a non fast-forward one.

Or, in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67690224/6309), you are pushing commits created with an email not yet verified.
That would be part of [GitLab push rules](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/push_rules/push_rules.html), like this other one:

> Restrict commits to existing GitLab users (checked against their emails).

Comment: The repo is empty, there are no commits. And I checked the status of my e-mail, it is verified. So, I guess, the problem is in something else

Comment: @Phelizer Is it gitlab.com? Are there any chance one of the push rules mentioned in https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/push_rules/push_rules.html is active?