# Heroku Python Deployment Version Issue

Tags: python, django, heroku

Heroku will not push my Python version for my Django app and I can't figure out why... I upgraded my python from 3.8.7 to 3.10.2 and reflected this within the runtime.txt file, and the changes are clearly added, but this isn't seeming to work.

From heroku's Python Support:

```
Supported runtimes
python-3.10.2 on all supported stacks
```

```
C:\Users\New User\Downloads\django-modal-ajax-crud-main\django-modal-ajax-crud-main>git push heroku main
Enumerating objects: 191, done.
Counting objects: 100% (191/191), done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (173/173), done.
Writing objects: 100% (191/191), 72.21 MiB | 1.24 MiB/s, done.
Total 191 (delta 35), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote:
remote: -----> Building on the Heroku-20 stack
remote: -----> Determining which buildpack to use for this app
remote: -----> Python app detected
remote: -----> Using Python version specified in runtime.txt
remote:  !     Requested runtime ("python-3.10.2") is not available for this stack (heroku-20).
remote:  !     Aborting.  More info: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-support
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
remote:
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote:
remote: !       Push rejected to whispering-oasis-59527.
remote:
To https://git.heroku.com/whispering-oasis-59527.git
 ! [remote rejected] main -> main (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/whispering-oasis-59527.git'
```

Comment: I'd open a Heroku support ticket. That seems like a bug.

Comment: Is your `runtime.txt` UTF-8 encoded?

Comment: However it's encoded, heroku is picking up the right request because it literally says `Requested runtime ("python-3.10.2")` in the error. Side note: the tag [tag:git] is inapplicable here. You're using Git to *store your repository* and to *ask Heroku to build* but Git isn't involved in producing any of the errors you see here: it's just relaying stuff *from Heroku*.

Comment: @RCarmody, also, what line endings does that file use?

Comment: I had something similar, I had to use the following command to debug it a bit more. It's not an answer, but maybe it can help you get closer? Note: I had this error as a result of my collect static phase. heroku config:set DEBUG_COLLECTSTATIC=1

Answer (score 0):

I really deployed with `3.10.2` now, so it's available

And so, You question seems to have a false error that is explained in the end of you output

```
Requested runtime ("python-3.10.2") is not available for this stack (heroku-20).
...
.. (pre-receive hook declined)
```

[docker documentaion](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-runtimes#selecting-a-runtime) says:

> The runtime.txt format is case-sensitive and must not include spaces.
> You must also specify all three version number components (major,
> minor, and patch) in runtime.txt.
>
> If you don’t follow this format, your app will fail to deploy.

so make sure no white spaces or new lines, and always keep track of [supported runtimes](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-support#supported-runtimes)

---

Additionally

You could remove `runtime.txt`,

[app.json](https://github.com/heroku/python-getting-started/blob/main/app.json) should have `"image": "heroku/python"` with **no version** or `python` in keywords,

then install with default version curently `3.9.10`,

and then you could update with `runtime.txt`

---

First of All: make sure your app is running properly on local machine

this could also to be a dependency error like this [first comment on this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7988885/9907243)

> Your app and build dependencies should be functional when deploying