# Recover uncommited changes on a branch

Tags: git

I start to work on some changes on my master branch and realize that this is not a quick fix and I will need more time to do my fix. So I save my work in a different branch as [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3899627/git-create-a-branch-with-current-changes) with:

```
git checkout -b newClientID
```

I didn't commit my change there, since I wanted to make more relevant progress.
Then I switch to my `master` and reset it

```
git checkout master
git checkout -- .
```

When I switch back to my branch `newClientID` I realize that my uncommitted changes have been lost. Any chance to recover them?

Comment: In the future, if you want to save changes without committing, you'll probably want to consider using `git stash`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't commit and reset the working tree, it's lost forever.

Next time, commit often, maybe more than necessary and eventually squash commits with interactive rebasing before pushing to remote.

By commiting, e.g. with `git commit -m wip`, I find it less error prone than `git stash` because it's all too easy to `git stash pop` in the wrong branch.

Comment: I guess I should have used git stash before changing branch. http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Stashing

Comment: Well I prefer `git commit -m wip` to `git stash` because it's too easy to `git stash pop` to the wrong branch

Comment: sorry... happened to me once, was on a mac, Time Machine backup saved my ass

Comment: I faced that problem either. Lucky, I'm using Java and IntellijIDEA, so I had an ability to get the changes from my compiled classes of target repository. Never the less you can try to get your changes from git local history.

Comment: In this scenario, if i didn't use reset/restore, would I be able to retrieve my changes?

Answer (score 0):

The same happened to me. this is a silly answer but it actually worked. I went to my files with the lost changes, ctrl+z and all the changes appeared.