# Git ahead of master, how to put the changes into a new local branch?

Tags: git

I'm in the

```
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 2 commits.
(use "git push" to publish your local commits)
```

state after making and committing some changes in my local master branch.

How do I pick off the local changes into a new branch?

My desired outcome is: local/master is synchronized with origin/master, and I have a local branch with the two commits in it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create Git branch with current changes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3899627/create-git-branch-with-current-changes)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First

```
git checkout -b newBranchName
```

this will create a new branch, the same as the current master you are working on.

After that,

```
git checkout master
```

this will select master as your current branch.

Finally

```
git reset --hard origin/master
```

this will remove those 2 commits from master, but they will be still available in `newBranchName`

EDIT: as @ShmulikKlein Mention, be careful with `--hard`.. you can always use `--soft` and then discard the changes

Answer (score 1):

@Matias is right, but first, you should be very careful when using `git reset --hard` as along with revretting the last 2 commits, it will also wipe out your entirely working directory and staging area (aka, unstaged and uncommited changes).

Second, I think that the last step should be `git reset --hard HEAD~2` when you are on the `master` branch, since you are only want to revert the last 2 commits, since you don't know how `origin/master` was changed since you post the question... (unless you check using `git status`...)