# Creating branch in git in master being in a another branch

Tags: git, git-branch

I want to do something like this.
I have a branch called branchA and i want to create a new branch. This new base if the new branch should be the master. How can i do this if i am working in the branchA

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create Git branch with current changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3899627/create-git-branch-with-current-changes)

Answer (score 1):

Pass `git branch` an extra argument indicating where to start from:

```
git branch branchB master
```

This will create a new branch `branchB` which will start where `master` currently points.

It won't switch branches, so if you're working on branch `branchA`, you will stay there... If you want to create a new branch and start working on it too, then use `checkout` with the `-b` argument for the branch name. You can also pass it an extra argument with the starting point:

```
git checkout -b branchB master
```

You can also pass a starting point from a remote by using a syntax such as `origin/master`.

Answer (score 0):

This could already be a possible duplicate, but the quick way to creating a new branch from your `master` branch can be done in the following.

On your `master` branch,

```
$ git checkout -b new-branch-name
```

---

If not on your `master` branch,

```
$ git checkout master
$ git checkout -b new-branch-name
```

Answer (score -1):

the git flow is as follow

- change branch to master from branchA  `git checkout master`
- pull to update `git pull`
- create and swap to new branch `git checkout -b new-branch`