# Revert changes in Git "main" to prior commit, after branching out with all changes since in "new-branch"

Tags: git, git-branch, git-commit, git-revert

I erred by working locally on a local repo's "*main*" branch, instead of branching out with a new branch and modifying code there. I brought more modifications to the code than I thought I would, all without pushing anything to remote "*origin*". A quick `$ git reflog --date=iso | grep pull` yielded the hash that corresponds to the pull from "*origin/main*", from which I should have branched out in the first place (and didn't), say it's "D".

Before restoring my local "*main*" to the prior state of interest, "D", I created a "*new-branch*". Now I have:

```
         E' (new-branch)
        /   
B--D--(E)   (main)
```

So currently E' reflects all changes locally made to D. What I would like is to end up with all changes reflected in E' to be as if they :

```
     E'     (new-branch)
    /   
B--D--      (main)
```

Not sure that the two schematics above are fully correct representation. In any case it's all local. Would doing

```
$ git checkout main
$ git checkout -b new-branch
$ git checkout main
$ git reset --soft <sha1_for-D>
```

revert all changes to previous state "D" on my local "*main*", while preserving changes stored in "*new-branch*" as "E'". But is this strictly equivalent to

```
$ git checkout main
$ git switch -c new-branch
$ git checkout main
```

as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3899627/create-git-branch-with-current-changes)?

Continuing to work on "*new-branch*" will eventually lead to a merge into "*main*" after testing. Will that future "merge" unfold any differently from a merge that would have occurred with no soft reset on "*main*" ?

Comment: I don't know.... I think it would be ok to create (or _place_ if it's already created) the new branch on `E'` (if it's not there already) and then just reset the local `main` to where `origin/main` is. The trick is to understand that branches are just _pointers to commits_ that you are free to move around at will, it's not like there's metadata in the commits that keeps track of the _branches_ that were used to create them.

Comment: By the way.... you could also consider keeping a local `main` branch is worth it if your goal about it is to keep it in perfect sync with `origin/main`. You can interact with `origin/main` without having to use the local `main` branch.

Comment: What is `(E)` in your chart? And a nice chart in the question having `main`, `origin/main` and `new-branch` would be awesome.... something like `git log --oneline --graph main origin/main new-branch`

Comment: @eftshift0: tx. I think I understand your first comment, but not sure I do your second one. How can I NOT use the local main branch if it is the backbone for all feature development and part of the testing ? -- As for (E), I put it in parentheses because this was a local commit I removed after creating the *new-branch*. Just my notation; sorry if not appropriate.

Comment: i think the chart with `git log` will help. If your muscle memory is used to using a local `main` branch, it's ok.... it's just unnecessary and you might be surprised how easy it is to avoid it... but it needs some adjustments that I won't be able to explain in a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your chart is a bit misleading, as there seems to be no commit `E'`. After `git checkout -n new-branch` both branches point to the same commit `E` like this:

```
C--D--E (main) (new-branch)
```

If you then checkout `main` and reset it to commit `D` as you proposed this will result in

```
     E (new-branch)
    /
C--D   (main)
```

You might want to consider using `git reset --hard` or at least switch back to the `new-branch` immediately after the reset to not have this somewhat confusing state of the repository with lots of uncomitted local changes that `git reset --soft` leaves behind.

Comment: Oh, I thought preserving the index was preferable to a hard reset, without fully understanding why that that would be an advantage if all code changes were effectively captured in E' (or E as per your chart) ... Also my bad for the initial typo on `git checkout -n..` . I fixed it to be `git checkout -b ...`. -- Finally I  did a hard reset, and everything went well. Tx,