# Add the file on the specific branch in git

Tags: git, github

I am new to git and hope using it properly.

```
git init
git add .      // added the whole directory
git commit -m "initial stage"
git checkout -b "version1"
git branch

  master
* version1
```

**Now i want to add some new files in the directory**

```
cp /path/to/file/admin.php /path/to/git/folder/.
```

**These files should include only on version1 branch but it is also including in the master branch**

```
git add admin.php
git status
On branch version1
Untracked files:
(use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
admin.php

git checkout master
git status
On branch master
Untracked files:
(use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
admin.php
```

*The question is how can i add files only on specific branch??*

Thanks

Comment: That file does not exist on *either* branch; it's "untracked", in git terminology.  Until you `git add` *and* `git commit` it will continue to not exist anywhere in the repository, only in your working directory.  You need to start with some [git basics](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Getting-Started-Git-Basics)...  (*Technically, `git add` will save it to something temporary, but it won't become permanent until the `git commit` step.)

Comment: @torek your comment is exact an answer. So why not answer?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2569513/3802077, what @torek said but with more info and more specific

Comment: @RomanGotsiy: Mostly because a full answer would take too long, and be redundant with other existing SO answers and the Pro Git book.  The question betrays a fundamental misunderstanding of git.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

In order to add files in specific branch follow the below instructions :

To create custom branch

```
git branch branchname
```

To switch into custom branch

```
git checkout branchname
```

To initialize in the custom branch

```
git init
```

To add files in the custom branch

```
git add file name
```

To commit the changes made in the custom branch

```
git commit -m "your message"
```

To make changes in your GitHub repo

```
git push
```

Hope you get clear cut idea.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes when you use

```
git add fileName
```

you get this error

> The following paths are ignored by one of your .gitignore files:
> fileName

In order to still add it, go to your .gitignore and comment the line associated with that file adding #,

```
#fileName
```

Then you will be able to add, commit, and push.