# Upon $ Git checkout branchName, all changes (committed or not/ staged or not) appear on branch switched

Tags: git, git-branch, git-checkout

## Git / branch weird behavior

Recently, I had to recover my computer and reinstalled ALL software again.

Git is behaving in a manner I am not familiar with.

I did

```
$ git init
$ git branch -b newBranch
$ git checkout newBranch
```

After this I did some changes to a couple of files and added a new file.

I DID NOT `$ git add -A` NOR `$ git commit -m 'msg'`

Upon,

```
$ git checkout master
```

all changes made on `newBranch` reflect on `master`:

- all changes made to all files on newBranch
- all new files created on newBranch

Upon,

```
$ git status
```

all changes show up as un-staged (in red).

Previously, whenever I switched to a branch and did some changes,
upon switching to another branch, I would NOT be able to see those changes anymore (staged/un-staged or committed/un-committed).

And only upon running

```
$ git merge sourceBranch destinationBranch
```

would those changes show on the other branches. This seems not to be the case

with my Git.

Is it

- broken?
- missconfigured?
- miss-installed?
- corrupted?
- what am I not understanding?

Comment: "Previously, whenever I switched to a branch and did some changes, upon switching to another branch, I would NOT be able to see those changes anymore (staged/un-staged or committed/un-committed)." I don't believe this is the case, some kind of confusion here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Previous installation misled me as to actual commands and Git capabilities.
Must read docs thoroughly.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: your local changes are not tracked by git until you `add` or `commit` them. If you switch branch without adding or committing, git does not overwrite these local changes, so you don't lose data too easily.

---

There are three separate domains:

- your local files (`L`)
- the staging area (`S`)
- the repository (`R`)

You have made changes in `L`. These do not reflect in `S` nor `R`, the domains are separated. If you haven't told git to `add` (to `S`) or `commit` (to `R`), your changes in `L` do not belong to any branch yet, only to the `L` domain.

When you `checkout` branches, from and to `master` and `newBranch`, git changes the current `HEAD`, that is were local changes *would* be introduced into `S` or `R`, if you were to `add` or `commit`.

When you `checkout` branches, git also attempts to reflect the checked out commit (which is the one at the tip of the branch you check out) onto the file system, domain `L`. *But*, to prevent shooting yourself in the foot and losing unstaged and uncommited changes in `L`, git does not overwrite these `L` changes. Since they're not added or commited, you couldn't retrieve them otherwise.

Note: you may tell git to overwrite such local changes, by passing the `-f` (force) flag to `checkout`. You'd lose your local changes without warning.

Note also: switching branch while having local changes is not always possible, for example if the branch being changed to would apply changes that would overwrite some of your local changes. This is where I most often use `-f`, when I know I want to lose the local changes.

This answer (mine) might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2569513/108802

Comment: I don't understand why when I checkout of a branch without doing add or commit, the source code on my code editor does not revert to the file without changes made in another branch; eventhough, I have not run $ git merge

Comment: You have not made changes in another branch until you commit these changes. You were on a branch (domain `R`), you made changes (domain `L`), but the changes themselves are just local, not on the branch.

Comment: `checkout` with `-f` and you'd get the behavior you expect. But your local changes would be lost, if never committed.

Comment: wow, aparently the way I configured my bash commands in my previous installation gave me the wrong idea of things.THANX a bunch. I have to read more the documentation.

Comment: @wowiamhere: good that you figured it out! Consider upvoting/accepting the answer if you consider your question solved.

Answer (score 0):

So you're now working on `newBranch` branch, you made changes but *didn't* commit anything yet.

**Why it's allowed to checkout the `master` branch?**

Git allows that because switching to it *won't* override any of your *local* changes.

However, if you're now working on `master` branch and change some files, Git will prevent you from doing that because local changes would be overwritten.

Comment: After 
* making changes in NewBranch (without staging), 
* switching to master and making some changes to the changes that show up from NewBranch, 
* and switching back to NewBranch,

I can see all changes made in master (still unstaged)

Answer (score 0):

It's not broken or anything try adding those unstage and commit again.