# git: Commit the currently uncommitted work in progress in the current branch to a new branch

Tags: git, version-control

Occasionally I find my self in the following situation:
I am working on branch (say master) and I am editing some files, but when it comes the time for a commit I realize that I would prefer to commit to a new branch (say experimental). In other words, the old branch (master) must remain intact and a new branch should be created that will look like:

```
.. -- master -- new commit
```

What is the easiest way to do that?

Currently, I commit to old branch, then create the new branch and finally reset the old branch. But that's really ugly.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Git: How to move existing work to new branch?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1394797/git-how-to-move-existing-work-to-new-branch)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
git checkout -b branch       # create new branch out of current head
git add <files>              # the changes you had done in your working directory will be carried over
git commit -m "message"      # commit!
```

Comment: its mentioned in the question "but when it comes the time for a commit I realize that I would prefer to commit to a new branch"

Comment: @user1004474 - Try it out. Both unstaged and stage changes will be there when you switch branch.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I thought checkout would discard all changes. It's confusing, sometimes the same git command does different things. It would be nice I could do something like:

git commit -b new_branch .......

Comment: well,I'm a beginner and I supposed that you should create a new branch before you make some changes! In this case user1004474 had already made the changes! So I was in a confusion.

Comment: see, I had this same doubt as the user1004474! :D

Comment: @user1004474 - That will not be the case because commits are not associated to branch, but to parent. There is plumbing commands that will allow you to create commits with particular parent that you want.

Answer (score 1):

It's slightly easier if you create the new branch first:

```
$ git checkout -b new_branch
$ git commit
```

Comment: The point is that I did not planned this ahead of time, so the changes were made first (and possible some of the added to the index with git add) and then I decide to branch.

Comment: @user1004474: It still works. You can run a `git checkout -b new_branch` regardless of whether you have changes and whether they have been added to the index or not.

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is for you to go ahead and commit them to the `master` branch, then cut off another branch from the new `HEAD` (say `feature`). Once this is done, you can `git reset` master to the position before the commits.

Comment: Ok, you did not read the `Currently, I commit to old branch, then create the new branch and finally reset the old branch. But that's really ugly.` then.

Comment: Yeah. I missed that. I don't think it's that ugly though FWIW.

Comment: Get makes it easy to do, but it is ugly IMO