# Moving uncommitted changes to a new branch

Tags: git

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Move existing, uncommited work to a new branch in Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1394797/move-existing-uncommited-work-to-a-new-branch-in-git)

I have some code in branch ABC.

After making some changes to it, i'd like to move all those uncommitted changes into a commit on a new branch ABC_1.

How can this be done please?

Answer (score 505, accepted):

Just create a new branch:

```
git checkout -b newBranch
```

And if you do `git status` you'll see that the state of the code hasn't changed and you can commit it to the new branch.

Comment: is there a way to push changes to an existing branch without committing uncommitted code to present branch?

Comment: @kRazzy R, probably a not-so-smart idea would be to create the new branch using `git checkout -b new_branch` and then merging the changes in the existing branch using `git merge`

Comment: Git 2.23 adds the new switch subcommand in an attempt to clear some of the confusion that comes from the overloaded usage of checkout (switching branches, restoring files, detaching HEAD, etc.)   
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1394797/move-existing-uncommitted-work-to-a-new-branch-in-git/1394804

Answer (score 52):

Just move to the new branch. The uncommited changes get carried over.

```
git checkout -b ABC_1

git commit -m <message>
```

Answer (score 22):

Just create a new branch with `git checkout -b ABC_1`; your uncommitted changes will be kept, and you then commit them to that branch.