# Create a new branch with committed, but unpushed changes

Tags: git

I got a git repository containing a `main`-branch.

Unfortunately I created a lot of new features there and committed the changes, but I did not push them yet.

Now I'd like to work on another computer, so my idea was to create a new branch from the committed, but unpushed changes on `main`.

### So my question is:

How to create a new branch called `version3` containing all those unpushed changes from `main` and remove those commits from `main` after that to get a `main`-branch that does not contain the new features until I merge them?

Comment: Hi, 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/14655842/1892085

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
# Create a new branch `version3` based on `main` and check it out
git checkout -b version3 main

# Push `version3` (-u to make the local branch track the remote branch)
git push -u

# Go on `main` and remove the commits you do not want
git checkout main
git reset --hard origin/main
```