# git checkout master automatically moves my other not committed branch changes

Tags: git

Let's suppose I am on master branch and then I do :

```
git branch new_branch
git checkout new_branch
touch newFile.txt
```

When I do git checkout master to come back to my master branch, I expect I have a clean workspace and no trace of newFile.txt. But git automatically moves newFile.txt in my master branch.

Is this the default git behavior? How could I change it?

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, but where do you want those changes to go?  Would you rather have git silently remove all changed files?

Comment: No, I suppose what I do in new_branch should stay in new_branch. If I start to do something on a branch, and then I have an emergency I have to switch to another one, I don't want to get the work done on the other branch.

Comment: @rico: you are not doing anything in new_branch, you are doing something in your working tree. And the working tree is not linked to any branch.

Comment: Your changes aren't on any branch until you commit them;  for this workflow, you need to either stash or commit your changes then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Uncommitted changes are not part of any branch, they live in the working copy. To remove untracked files, use the `git clean` command. This is default behavior of Git and cannot be changed.

Also, see [Move existing, uncommited work to a new branch in Git](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1394797/112968). Whether or not the branch is new or an existing does not really matter.