# How to check out a new branch after changes have already been made

Tags: git

I usually start editing files by creating a new branch: `git checkout new-feature`

But this time i forgot to create a new branch and started editing files. I have not added or committed anything yet.

Is there a way I can make a branch now and still have all the edits I've made thus far?

Comment: Just make a new branch and check it out.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Move existing, uncommited work to a new branch in Git](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1394797/move-existing-uncommited-work-to-a-new-branch-in-git)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to create a new branch off the current branch with all the work you are currently working on (i.e. with a dirty working directory), you can just create the branch and switch to it:

```
git checkout -b new-feature
```

Git will not touch your changes at all. And if Git had a problem that would require Git to change things, it wouldn’t do so but instead stop and tell you that you can’t do it without losing changes.