# Git : Move staged changes to different or new branch

Tags: git

I can currently do it by following these three steps

1. Unstage by using `git reset HEAD <file>...`
2. checkout to the branch `git checkout [-b] <branchname>`
3. Stage again `git add <file>...`

Is there a better way of moving the staged changes?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Move existing, uncommited work to a new branch in Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1394797/move-existing-uncommited-work-to-a-new-branch-in-git)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[Edmundo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44162267/1256452) is the right one, but it could use some details about *why* it's the right one.

There are two cases of interest here:

- Making a *new* branch that starts from the commit where you are now is trivially easy:

  ```
  $ git checkout -b newbranch
  ... continue working; git add and/or git commit as usual ...
  ```

  The `git checkout -b` step never fails as long as the new branch itself is OK (has a valid name that does not collide with an existing name).
- Moving to some *other, already-existing* branch *may* be trivially easy:

  ```
  $ git checkout otherbranch
  ... continue working ...
  ```

  *If* that fails, you will want/need to make at least one commit.

  You can make this commit as an ordinary commit, that you then copy to the new branch and remove from the current branch; or you can use `git stash`, which actually makes *two* commits.<sup>1</sup>  It's just that these two commits are not on *any* branch, which makes it more obvious that `git stash apply` can re-apply those commits anywhere.  (Using `git stash pop` is just saying `git stash apply && git stash drop`, i.e., apply and then, if Git thinks that went OK—whether or not it really did go well—drop the stash.  I recommend splitting the two so that you can *check* whether it went well, though usually it does and in the end this is *usually* quite minor.)

---

<sup>1</sup>These two commits are to save (a) the index/staging area, and (b) corresponding files (i.e., all tracked files) in the work-tree.  If you use `git stash save --untracked` or `git stash save --all`, it actually makes *three* commits.  You probably don't want the three-commit form, which is substantially trickier.

---

#### What's going on

When you have made changes, these changes are stored in files.  These files appear in one or both of two places:

- your work tree, which is where you have your files in ordinary-file-form, so that you can work with them (hence the name "work tree"); or
- your staging area, which Git also calls the *index*.

The index or staging area is where you build the *next* commit you will make.  Normally, it already has in it—it *starts out* with—all the files from your *current* commit, in the same form they have in the current commit (which, incidentally, is *always* known as `HEAD`).  That is, you run:

```
git checkout <branch-name-or-commit-hash-or-similar>
```

and *both* your work tree *and* your index/staging-area get filled in so that they match the commit you just checked out, which now known as `HEAD`.  (If you check out a branch name, the *commit* you're checking out is the latest, or *tip*, commit on that branch.)  Let's say, for instance, that you did `git checkout master`.

If you don't touch the index and work tree at this point, you can, obviously, `git checkout` *any other* commit, e.g., `git checkout develop`.  It's fine for Git to throw away the versions in your index and work-tree, because they match the commit you *had* checked out.  If it tosses out a `README` file, or even your entire working set of files, so what?  They're still in that other commit, the tip commit of `master`.  You can just `git checkout master` again when you want them back.

But that's not the case you care about here.  Here, you *have* modified some files.  You may even have run `git add` to *stage* them for the next commit.  But all `git add README` does is to *copy* the file from the work-tree into the index.  This means that the index and the work-tree versions of `README` match *each other*.  They both *don't* match the `HEAD` (current) commit.

Let's say that `HEAD` is the tip of `develop` and you should have been on `feature` instead.  You'd like to `git checkout feature`.  But what will happen to `README`?  You made a change.  You maybe even *staged* it, copying it into the index.

Well, the fact is, Git is *lazy*.  If you now run `git checkout feature` to move the `HEAD` commit to the tip of branch `feature`, Git will have to do some work.  That *might* include removing the current `README` file and replacing it with the one from the tip of `feature`.

But maybe—just *maybe*—the tip commit of `feature` has the *same* `README` file as the tip commit of `develop`.  If so, Git can be lazy!  Git can simply *not bother* ripping out the existing `README` from the index/staging-area and/or work-tree.  It can *leave* the modified `README` in whichever places it is now.  And that's precisely what Git does.

If Git *can't* be lazy about the files, it *checks*.  If you the files you have in your index and/or work-tree *don't* match the ones in the `HEAD` commit you are trying to move off of, then `git checkout feature` *fails*.  (See [the `git read-tree` documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-read-tree.html) and its list of—yikes!—[*21* possible cases for a "two tree merge"](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-read-tree.html#_two_tree_merge), to see *exactly* which ones succeed and which ones fail.  Mostly, though, you don't have to *care* about all of this: if it succeeds, you're good, if it fails, you have to commit or stash.)

This is why `git checkout -b newbranch` always succeeds: it creates the new branch with that branch-name pointing to the current (`HEAD`) commit.  Then it switches from the `HEAD` commit to ... well, itself.  There's nothing to switch.  The laziness step applies to *every* file: no file must be changed, so no file *is* changed, so `git checkout -b` just works.

And, this is why `git checkout -b otherbranch` *sometimes* succeeds: it needs to switch from the `HEAD` commit to the tip of `otherbranch`.  If that commit has some files that are different, Git will have to rip out the ones that are in the index/staging-area and work-tree right now, and replace them with the versions from the tip of `otherbranch`.  This is only allowed if the versions that are in the index/staging-area and work-tree right now *match* the versions in the `HEAD` commit.

Comment: Very informative @torek, however I'd like to be certain of something. git checkout (with staged changes) will check that the modified files on the revision you want to checkout are _exactly_ the same as in HEAD? I would assume that it doesn't have to be exactly the same content.... I _think_ git checks for possible _conflicts_ when checking out (which means that files might be different but as long as the staged changes can be applied successfully, git will move on with the checkout).

Comment: It's a bit tricky because `git checkout` allows using `-m` to do merges (of commits; it also allows `-m` on files but those work differently). Essentially, `git checkout` runs `git read-tree` to do either a two or three way merge. The rules for these are spelled out in the `git read-tree` documentation. Even with some compression there are 21 rows of rules (!) for a two-tree "merge".

Answer (score 8):

Using the stash is very helpful in this situation.

```
git stash

git checkout someBranch

git stash pop
```

Answer (score 7):

Just checking out where you want to move them should be enough. Git performs a check to see if the staged changes can be applied on the point you are checking out without conflicts. Another easy technique you can use is to stash the changes, then checkout the branch and then stash pop.