# Moving all current uncommitted work in master branch to some other branch instead

Tags: git, version-control, branch, git-branch

I am new to Git and learning to use it for my project. Currently, I'm wondering how to switch uncommitted work to a branch when I have accidentally been working in `master`. I am working on my own, but want to keep things organized anyway.

For example, I have made a series of commits and `master` is up to date. I then begin working on the master branch, but decide the work will be more involved than predicted, so I would prefer to be doing it in some other branch.

I can certainly commit the changes up till then to `master` and then start from there in a new branch, but I would rather have all the stuff I've been doing since my last commit in that new branch. What is the simple approach to doing this?

Is this a case where a `git reset --soft` would be needed? Or is there a simpler approach? Thanks.

Comment: Just start the new branch (e.g. `git co -b branchname`), it will come with all the commits and any uncommitted WIP you had on the branch you started from.

Comment: I thought it might be simple! Thank you for that help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Move existing, uncommitted work to a new branch in Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1394797/move-existing-uncommitted-work-to-a-new-branch-in-git)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see three cases :

1. you want to continue on a new branch, created from the las commit on `master` :

   ```
   git checkout -b name-of-new-branch
   ```

   Then you can commit in the new branch
2. you want to continue on an existing branch (`that-branch`), and the current WIP touches no file that is different in `that-branch` and in `master` (don't worry, git will complain if that's the case) :

   ```
   git checkout that-branch
   ```

   If the checkout works, you can commit
3. some files are different in `that-branch` and in `master` (git complained when you tried 2. :

   ```
   git stash
   git checkout that-branch
   git stash apply
   ```

There may be conflicts that you have to then resolve. If you can't (merges can be hard), don't feel overwhelmed, and `git reset HEAD --hard`. The stash will still be here and you can go back to `master` and do step 1, before trying to merge in a conventional way.

You could also `git stash pop`, but I always stress that I'll lose work if it fails.