# Retargeting a branch

Tags: git, bitbucket

I’m new to git. I have a master branch that has several branches off of it, such as branch1, branch2, branch3, etc. I checked out a feature branch off of branch1, and made some changes. I haven’t commit or pushed my changes yet, but since it has been a while since I started the ticket, I should now be targeting branch3 instead. How do I go about this? Would I just have to retarget the PR to branch3 on bitbucket, or do I have to do something in git?

I’m confused about if this needs any changes in git or if I would just need to retarget in bitbucket.

Comment: "I haven't committed my changes yet" - in these cases I go via stash. `git stash; git checkout branch3; git stash pop`

Comment: @RomainValeri hard reset would lose the uncommitted changes, though?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev You're right, I didn't notice that OP didn't mention pending changes. Also, stashing is useless here. Just checkout. IF it's not possible due to file changes between branches, git will suggest the stash, but it's unnecessary by default.

Comment: @RomainValeri: naked checkout will fail if branch3 touched some of the files you changed.

Comment: "I haven't committed anything yet" and "should I retarget the PR" don't go together. Either you have commits in a PR or you haven't committed anything. You can't have both at the same time.

Comment: Does this answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1394797/move-existing-uncommitted-work-to-a-new-branch-in-git/1394804#1394804?

Comment: @knittl You are wrong. It is possible to create a PR before committing any changes to a branch.

Comment: I haven’t created the PR yet. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

You may simply create and checkout the feature branch you want from the correct base branch:

```
# from branch1
git checkout -b your_feature branch3
# work work work
```

Your uncommitted work will happily sit there while you create your intended feature branch.  Note the 2 argument form of `git checkout`, where the first branch is the one to be created and the second one is the source branch (which is not the current `branch1`).

Comment: I would recommend that we not tell beginners to use `git checkout`. It is superseded by the much more well-behaved `git switch`. So the command here would be `git switch -C your_feature branch3`, I believe (I think `git switch -c` with a lowercase `c` would fail on the grounds that the branch already exists).

Comment: So I would do this off of branch1, correct? Why is that? What would happen if I did it off of the feature branch? Just trying to understand how it works.

Comment: My answer creates a new branch `your_feature` from `branch3` as a starting point _and_ it also switches to that new branch.  It should work correctly from _any_ starting branch.

Comment: Okay makes sense. I did that but it says “featureBranch is ahead of featureBranch by 100 commits”. Is this because branch3 had changes that branch1 didn’t?

Answer (score 0):

Since you haven't committed your changes yet, you can simply switch your current branch to the existing target branch using [**git-switch**](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-switch) like this:

```bash
git switch branch3
```

Then you can commit your changes and push the branch to BitBucket.

If you already have an empty PR to merge **branch1**, you should close it and open a new PR to merge **branch3** instead.