# Github: Import upstream branch into fork

Tags: git, github

I have a fork (`origin`) from a project (`upstream`) on github. Now the upstream project has added a new branch, I want to import into my fork. How do I do that?

I tried checking out the remote and creating a branch on top of that, but that configures the branch the way that `git push` is trying to push to the `upstream`:

```
git checkout upstream/branch
git checkout -b branch
```

#### edit

Maybe that wasn't clear, but I want to add the branch to my local repository, so I can push it to `origin` (my fork) via `git push`. Because upstream repositories are usually read-only and you fork it to contribute.

So I basically want to checkout a non-existent branch on `origin` whose contents will be pulled in from `upstream`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I check out a remote Git branch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1783405/how-do-i-check-out-a-remote-git-branch)

Comment: @MichaelFreidgeim My question was basically asking about the `-u` option, when dealing with *multiple* remotes. The accepted answer covers in this question covers that just fine.

Comment: Sorry for the automatically created unintentional question - the comment should be read as  [“Possible duplicate”](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/339563/the-auto-comment-does-this-answer-your-question-generated-when-voting-to-clos)

Answer (score 360, accepted):

1. Make sure you've pulled the new **upstream** branch into your **local repo**:

   - First, **ensure your working tree is clean** (commit/stash/revert any changes)
   - Then, `git fetch upstream` to retrieve the new upstream branch
2. Create and switch to a **local version of the new upstream branch** (**`newbranch`**):

   - `git checkout -b newbranch upstream/newbranch`
3. When you're ready to push the new branch to **origin**:

   - `git push -u origin newbranch`

The **-u** switch sets up tracking to the specified remote (in this example, **`origin`**)

Comment: I believe `git fetch upstream` is a better option at the first step, since `git pull upstream` requires more actions to be done after `git remote add ...` for the `upstream`.

Comment: git pull upstream returns: `You asked to pull from the remote 'upstream', but did not specify a branch. Because this is not the default configured remote for your current branch, you must specify a branch on the command line.` Adding the branch name at the end of the command causes a merge between the branch in the upstream with the current local branch instead of allowing the creation of a new local branch. Any ideas?

Comment: Replacing `git pull upstream` with `git fetch upstream` solved the problem, and the following steps worked.

Comment: I get:
fatal: Cannot update paths and switch to branch 'upstream' at the same time.
Did you intend to checkout 'upstream/master' which can not be resolved as commit?

Comment: @sureshvv That's probably because you need to have a remote reference to the upstream repository named **upstream** before doing any of that. In case you don't, that's how you add one: **git remote add upstream your_git_upstream_repository_url.git**. [Read this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9257901/4905310) if you need clarification on that matter.

Comment: @sureshvv Or you made a typo in the branch name under upstream/ - the branch `upstream/foo` wasn't found.

Comment: The `git checkout -b branchname upstream/branchname` doesn't work if I have a `/` in the branch name. For example, if the upstream has a branch named `feature/xyz` and I run `git checkout -b feature/xyz upstream/feature/xyz`, I get an error: `fatal: A branch named 'feature/logger' already exists.` Why is this? It works with branch names that don't have `/` in the name.

Comment: Worth noting is this guide, for when you need to _update_ the upstream branch into  a fork: https://help.github.com/en/articles/merging-an-upstream-repository-into-your-fork

Answer (score 22):

From the UI:

In your fork go to Branches, click 'New Branch'. There you would select the source - either your fork or upstream. Select upstream and select the branch that you want to 'import'. Create the branch with the same name. Done.

Comment: exactly what I came here looking for +1

Answer (score 11):

I had trouble with this too, and google took me here.  The solutions didn't work however.  My problem was that when i added my upstream, it set up my git config to only fetch master, rather than all branches.
e.g. It looked like this

```
[remote "somebody"]
        url = git@github.com:somebodys/repo.git
        fetch = +refs/heads/master:refs/remotes/upstream/master
```

Editing .git/config as follows fixed my problem

```
[remote "somebody"]
        url = git@github.com:somebodys/repo.git
        fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/upstream/*
```

Answer (score 9):

I would use

```
git checkout -b <new_branch> upstream/<new_branch>
```

Comment: That's actually what I tried even before what I have explained in the question; it leads to the same results.

Answer (score 2):

The following steps worked well for me (assuming the upstream branch name is `branch`):

```
$ git fetch upstream
$ git checkout branch
$ git push origin
```

Comment: I get git fetch upstream
fatal: 'upstream' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.

Comment: @ThinkDigital I got the same error, so git fetch simply works! 
Also, +1 for the comment in parentheses!

Comment: After I try git checkout on the new upstream branch, `git status` reveals that i'm still on my old branch and nothing happened.

Answer (score 2):

I had a slightly more complicated scenario where I already had an `upstream` defined in my fork (from the canonical repo) but needed to checkout a branch from a different fork. To get that done, the process is slightly different. Here's the config I ended up with:

```
[remote "origin"]
url = git@github.com:<your_user/org>/<repo>.git
fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*

[branch "master"]
remote = origin
merge = refs/heads/master
rebase = true

[remote "upstream"]
url = git@github.com:<upstream_user>/<repo>.git
fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/upstream/*

[remote "other_user"]
url = git@github.com:<other_user>/<repo>.git
fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/<other_user>/*
```

Now you can checkout a branch from `<other_user>` fork as well.

```
git fetch <other_user> <branch>
git checkout -b <branch> <other_user>/<branch>
```

That will give you a local branch which is derived from the <other_user> fork.

To push that local branch I had to be specific with my push command.

```
git push origin <branch>
```

Comment: That’s pretty much the same as the accepted answer, just that the remote you are fetching from is not called “upstream”.

Answer (score 0):

`--track`?

```
git branch --track branch upstream/branch
```

Comment: Maybe I understood you wrong, but doing that will set up the branch in the same way; with `push` pusing to `upstream`.

Comment: No, I think I misunderstood you.