# re-sync fork with parent git repo

Tags: git, github

I have forked a repo on github and the repo I have forked from has since added a new branch.  I would like to get that branch into my local fork and work on it.  Afterwards I would like to commit to that branch (which is in my local fork) and then submit a pull request to the original parent repo.

What ends up happening when I try to do this is as follows

1. Fork from parent repo
2. Parent repo then makes a new branch
3. On my local machine I do: git remote add parent https://github.com/PARENT/parentProj.git
4. git pull parent [new branch name]
5. Now I try: git checkout [new branch name] and I get "Branch [new branch name] set up to track remote branch [new branch name] from parent.
   Switched to a new branch '[new branch name]'
6. I think I am good but I am not.  Now when I make my changes and git push I get "remote: Permission to PARENT/parentProj.git denied to [me]."

I believe it is trying to push to the parent project new branch and not my fork of it.

How do I get it to let me push to the new branch on my fork so that I can then issue a pull request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I should have just searched more (or known better what to search for).  This answer solved my problem: [Github: Import upstream branch into fork](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4410091/github-import-upstream-branch-into-fork)

Answer (score 1):

When you do a git branch -avv, Git will show you which remote branches your local branches are "connected to".

```
$> git branch -avv
* master                a1b2c3d [origin/master] Some commit message here
```

That `[origin/master]` part means that if you update this branch, and attempt a `git push`, that's where it'll try to push.

In your case, I'd suggest re-assigning that remote's URL, but for `push` only. It seems you're always going to want to `fetch` from the parent fork, and `push` to your local, correct? If that's the case, then try this:

```
git remote set-url --push origin git@github.com:YourUser/theRepository.git
```

This way, when you pull, it comes from the parent fork, and when you push, it goes to your own fork. Then, you use the pull-request mechanism to get your code from your local fork to the parent.

Comment: That is kind of what I want but not quite.  Really I just want to tell my fork to re get all of the things from the parent. Commits, branches, etc.  As if I had blown away my entire fork and redone it.  That is the only way I have found to get everything all synced up correctly, but was hoping there was a better way.