# Difference between `git checkout -b newbranch upstream/newbranch` and `git checkout newbranch`

Tags: git, git-branch, git-checkout, git-fork, upstream-branch

I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4410502/3882565) answer about importing an upstream branch into a fork. The answer suggests using `git checkout -b newbranch upstream/newbranch` to switch to the new branch. I always just used `git checkout newbranch` in this case and it worked aswell. Is there any difference between these commands? My guess is that I only need `-b` to specify a branch name in case it should be different from `upstream/newbranch`. But if I just want the branch with its original name `newbranch`, is there any difference between using `git checkout -b newbranch upstream/newbranch` and `git checkout newbranch`? I have read the [docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout#Documentation/git-checkout.txt-emgitcheckoutem-b-Bltnewbranchgtltstartpointgt) of `-b` but that doesn't actually answer my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The existing answer doesn't cover *exactly* how this works, which is a little bit complicated.  Internally, Git calls this thing *DWIM mode*.

#### Long-ish: background

Let's start with this: your branch names are *yours*.  Some other Git might have a branch named `newbranch`, or `branch2`, or whatever, but if you don't have that branch name, you just don't have that branch name.  Well, not *yet*.

Remember also that every commit has a unique hash ID.  To see the hash ID of the current commit, run:

```
git rev-parse HEAD
```

The special name `HEAD` always names the *current commit* (and usually names the current *branch name* too, but we'll leave that for later).  The `git rev-parse` command will get you the big ugly hash ID—not all that useful to humans, but crucial for Git, because that hash ID is how Git actually finds the commit.

Meanwhile, each branch name just holds one (1) commit hash ID.  If you have a branch name `master`, you can find the hash ID that this name represents by running `git rev-parse master`.  As before, `git rev-parse` turns the name into the big ugly hash ID.

Now, this means that to create a *new* branch name, you tell Git: *Make a new branch name.  Here is the hash ID to store in it: _______*.  The *way* you tell this to Git is to use any of various commands:

- `git branch newname`: this tells Git to create the new name using the hash ID found by resolving `HEAD` to a hash ID.
- `git branch newname hash-id`: this tells Git to create the new name using the hash ID you type in.  Hash IDs are hard to type in, so you'd probably use the mouse to cut and paste one.  But you don't have to, because:
- `git branch newname any-other-name-that-works-with-rev-parse`: this has Git run `git rev-parse` on the *last* name, to find the hash ID, then create the branch so that it contains the hash ID you gave it.
- `git checkout -b name` and `git checkout -b name start-point`: these are very similar to using `git branch` followed by running `git checkout`.

But there's one more way to create a *new* branch name, and that's to run `git checkout name-that-does-not-yet-exist`.

Normally, if you do something like `git checkout supercalifragialistic`, you just get an error: Git tries to turn that name into a hash ID (using an internal equivalent of `git rev-parse`) and this fails entirely and the whole thing just stops with an error.  But `git checkout` has built into it a special trick.

Now, besides *branch* names, Git supports something that I call *remote-tracking names* (Git calls them *remote-tracking branch names* but the word *branch* here is kind of misleading, so I think it's better to leave it out).  These are pretty simple, really: your Git connects to some other Git, when you tell it to.  You probably call that other Git `origin`, since that's the standard name.  You will occasionally run `git fetch origin` or `git pull origin master` or some such: the name `origin` here is how your Git finds the URL to use to call up the other Git.

That other Git, over at `origin`, has branch names.  *Your* Git *remembers* their branch names, but since your names are yours, your Git remembers them under alternate names.  These are the remote-tracking names.  Your Git renames their `master` to your `origin/master`, renames their `xyz` to `origin/xyz`, and so on.

In your question you talked about `upstream/newbranch`.  The name `upstream` is the standard name for a *second* Git repository, that you add with `git remote add`.  There's one name for each "other Git" you talk to, and the remote-tracking names have the *remote* name, followed by the other Git's *branch* name, with a slash between them.  So you might end up with both `origin/newbranch` *and* `upstream/newbranch`, and this matters below.

#### DWIM mode

When you run a `git checkout` that *would* error out because you don't have the branch, `git checkout` will try a new trick before actually failing.

Your Git will scan through *all* of your remote-tracking names.  For instance, you might have `origin/master`, `origin/xyz`, `upstream/xyz`, and `upstream/newbranch`.

If you already have a `master` and run `git checkout master`, well, *you* have a `master`, so that's the one `git checkout` will use.  But if you run `git checkout newbranch` and don't have a newbranch, Git will scan all the above.  Only `upstream/newbranch` "looks right", so Git will say to itself: *Aha, if I automatically **create** `newbranch` from `upstream/newbranch` right now, I can switch **to** it!*  So that's what it does: *create* this as a new branch, and then switch to it.  The assumption is that while you said *switch to existing branch `newbranch`*, you must have **meant** *create new branch `newbranch` from `upstream/newbranch`*.  Git does what you meant, instead of what you said.

Note that if you run `git checkout xyz`, Git has a new problem: there are now *two* candidates from which to create `xyz`.  It could be created from `origin/xyz`, or from `upstream/xyz`.  By default, DWIM mode will just not create anything, and you'll see the error.

(Git 2.21 and later have `--no-guess` to disable DWIM entirely.  This is mainly useful with the bash completion scripts, if you don't want Git to guess all possible remote-tracking names.)

#### Several other important things to know

When you create a new branch name, you can have Git set its *upstream:*

- Every branch name has either one upstream, or no upstream.
- Typically the upstream for `master` would be `origin/master`, for instance.
- The upstream setting gives you more information from `git status`, and lets you run `git fetch`, `git merge`, `git rebase`, and `git pull` without specifying anything more.  So it's meant to be convenient.  If you find it convenient, use it; if not, don't.

To set the upstream of a branch explicitly, use `git branch --set-upstream-to`; to remove the upstream, use `git branch --unset-upstream`.  When `git checkout` uses DWIM mode to create a branch, it will normally set the upstream of that branch to the remote-tracking name it used when creating the branch.  You can adjust this with `git config`; see [its documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config).

When using `git branch` or `git checkout -b`, you can explicitly tell Git whether to set the upstream of the newly-created branch, using the `-t` or `--track` option (these are the same option: one is just a longer spelling).  Note that in the tricky case of having both `origin/xyz` *and* `upstream/xyz`, using:

```
git checkout -t origin/xyz
```

is a short-hand way of running:

```
git checkout -b xyz --track origin/xyz
```

That is, it:

1. specifies the name to use to get the hash ID when creating `xyz` locally;
2. specifies that the local name is `xyz` because the remote-tracking branch used is `origin/xyz`; and
3. specifies that new local `xyz` should be set with `origin/xyz` as its upstream.

Using `git checkout -t upstream/xyz` works similarly, except that your new `xyz` uses the commit ID found by resolving `upstream/xyz` and your new `xyz` has `upstream/xyz` as its upstream.

Answer (score 1):

The `-b` command creates a new branch and checks it out. Whereas `git checkout branch` checks out an already existing branch. Note, if you already have `newbranch` tracked locally then `git checkout -b newbranch` or `git checkout -b newbranch upstream/newbranch` will throw an error.

For example. Say you do not have a branch called `random`. Then the following gives an error:

```
git checkout random
```

But this creates and checks out `random`:

```
git checkout -b random
```

Conversely, if you have a branch called `random` the first command switches you to branch random whereas the second will throw an error.

Comment: I don't fully understand it. After `git fetch upstream` the `newbranch` exists anyway. Why do I need `-b` then? Isn't the linked answer in my question wrong then?

Comment: No, `git fetch upstream` only updates the references to the `upstream`. For example, getting changes to existing branches and having record of new branches. But these branches are still possibly distinct from your upstream branches. That's what `git pull` is for. For example you could have `master`, `branch1`, and `branch2` locally and then someone else working on the same repo creates `branch3`. `git fetch` will only show you that branch exists. But you still don't have `branch3` locally

Comment: You could then decide in parallel to create `branch4` locally with `git checkout -b branch4`. At this point `upstream` does not have record of `branch4` until you do `git push upstream branch4`.

Comment: But I had the situation multiple times. `upstream` created a `newbranch`. Locally I only did `git fetch upstream` and `git checkout newbranch`. It always worked. Why does it work? Or is there any difference I didn't notice?

Comment: Yes that will work because `newbranch` exists in `upstream` but if you instead wanted `newbranch2` you would need to write `git checkout -b newbranch2`. (That is `newbranch2` does not exist in `upstream`)

Comment: In this case, if you did `git checkout -b newbranch` this creates a new branch called `newbranch` locally. But this branch is distinct form `upstream\newbranch` whereas `git checkout newbranch` will checkout the `upstream` `newbranch` locally