# Checking out remote git branch?

Tags: git

Hey guys how would I checkout a specific branch from another remote address?

Thanks

Comment: you can check what branches you have by: git branch -a. Then follow instructions in VonC answer

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1783405/git-checkout-remote-branch?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
git checkout -b abranch origin/abranch
```

would allow you to create your own local branch, starting from a remote called origin, for the remote branch abranch.

That supposes you have declared a remote (which is done automatically when you clone a remote repo, declaring '`origin`' as the default name for referencing all refspecs from that repo in the `remotes/origin` namespace)

If you have already an 'origin' upstream repo from your original clone, but you want to add *another* repo as a source for your pull/push workflow, see [`git remote`](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-remote.html) (i.e `git remote add ...`).