# How do I fetch only one branch of a remote Git repository?

Tags: git

I'd like to grab a single branch (not all of them) of a remote repository and create a local tracking branch that can track further updates to that remote branch.  The other branches in the remote repository are very big, so I'd like to avoid fetching them.  How do I do this?

Comment: A git clone fetches the whole repository, including all branches. You can make shallow copies, but that only allows you to specify the number of revisions, not which branches.

Comment: git clone just takes master. if you git fetch, it takes all branches

Comment: "A git clone fetches the whole repository, including all branches" - not necessarily true, if you fetch exactly one branch, git will fetch all of the repository objects that are ancestors of the branch.   Many other branches may remain unfetched. Repositories with many branches (thousands) can improve fetch latency by only fetching specific branches.

Answer (score 377):

```
git fetch <remote_name> <branch_name>
```

Worked for me.

Comment: Just learned that the fetched branch is available as `FETCH_HEAD` after fetching. Thanks!

Comment: then `git checkout FETCH_HEAD` to checkout

Comment: How to get <remote_name> ?

Comment: @mrgloom in most cases `remote_name` is `origin`. eg: `git fetch origin <branch_name>`

Comment: The problem with (just) this is, that when you accidentially run the the simple form `git fetch <remote>` later "as usual", you will suddenly fetch all of the big repo. Thus its better to limit the fetching by config - e.g. via `git remote set-branches [--add] <name> <branch>…​` or (from the beginning) via `git clone --single-branch ...`

Comment: @mrgloom `git remote -v`

Answer (score 139):

I know there are a lot of answers already, but these are the steps that worked for me:

1. `git fetch <remote_name> <branch_name>`
2. `git branch <branch_name> FETCH_HEAD`
3. `git checkout <branch_name>`

These are based on the answer by @Abdulsattar Mohammed, the comment by @Christoph on that answer, and these other stack overflow questions and their answers:

- [How do I check out a remote Git branch?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1783405/how-do-i-check-out-a-remote-git-branch)
- [What does FETCH_HEAD in Git mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9237348/what-does-fetch-head-in-git-mean)

If the step #2 is skipped, you will have this error:

```
error: pathspec '<branch_name>' did not match any file(s) known to git
```

Comment: Most useful answer here IMO

Comment: This fails as follows if the branch already exists locally: `fatal: A branch named '<branch_name>' already exists.` Therefore I provided this [improved solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70441995/3162788) based on your proposal.

Comment: This is the only answer that actually worked for me as well.

Comment: When I run command #1, I'm left at the tip of the default branch, not the branch I specified.

Comment: Limitation of this approach: it will fail if the branch already exists locally (`fatal: a branch named '<branch_name>' already exists`). For a solution that works even then, see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70441995/3162788.

Comment: Steps 1 and 3 are enough I think

Answer (score 91):

One way is the following:

```
git fetch <remotename> <remote branch>:refs/remotes/<remotename>/<local branch>
```

This does not set up tracking though.

For more information, see [the documentation of git fetch](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-fetch.html).

**EDIT**: As @user1338062 [notes below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30588132/17916): if you don't already have a local clone of the repository where you want to add the new branch, but you want to create a fresh local repository, then the `git clone --branch <branch_name> --single-branch <repo_url>` provides a shorter solution.

Comment: Thanks this does what the op has asked. To make a tracking branch
git checkout -t <remote branch>/<branch name> <branch name>

Comment: If I simply do `git checkout <branchname>`, I see that git automatically sets up the tracking branch, if the only branch with that name is the remote branch.

Comment: this was the only thing that worked for me. even though the config was set to just fetch refs for a single branch, it still pulled refs to all branches using fetch or pull. this command pulled only the branch i wanted so the repo was only 500kb not 5mb. thanks.

Comment: This is the key to the solution.  Setting up branch tracking is a bit of a separate issue, but this is the command that will only fetch the commits that are needed for that one branch, rather than spending time updating all the other branches on the repo that you maybe don't care about.

Comment: This answer is probably outdated. `git clone` now supports `--branch` and `--single-branch` options, I posted [an answer with demonstration](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30588132/1338062).

Comment: @user1338062 This is still valid if you want to fetch a new branch only (not all branches using git fetch) after cloning

Answer (score 48):

To update existing remote to track specific branches only use:

```
git remote set-branches <remote-name> <branch-name>
```

From `git help remote`:

```
set-branches
    Changes the list of branches tracked by the named remote. This can be used to track a subset of the available remote branches
    after the initial setup for a remote.

    The named branches will be interpreted as if specified with the -t option on the git remote add command line.

    With --add, instead of replacing the list of currently tracked branches, adds to that list.
```

Comment: Amazing, I was in a `--single-branch` repository and could not download additional branches later. Thanks!

Answer (score 33):

One way to do it:

in .git/config fetch for the remote repo should be set to fetch any branch:

```
   [remote "origin"]
            fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

to fetch the remote branch:

```
git fetch origin branch-name
```

to create a local branch 'branch-name' set up to track remote branch 'branch-name' from origin.

```
git checkout -b branch-name origin/branch-name
```

to list all branches

```
git branch -a
```

Answer (score 18):

The answer actually depends on the current list of tracking branches you have. You can fetch a specific branch from remote with `git fetch <remote_name> <branch_name>` **only if** the branch is already on the tracking branch list (you can check it with `git branch -r`).

Let's suppose I have cloned the remote with --single-branch option previously, and in this case the only one tracking branch I have is the "cloned" one. I am a little bit bewildered by advises to tweak git config manually, as well as by typing `git remote add <remote_name> <remote_url>` commands. As "git remote add" sets up a new remote, it obviously doesn't work with the existing remote repository; supplying "-t branch" options didn't help me.

In case the remote exists, and the branch you want to fetch exists in that remote:

1. Check with `git branch -r` whether you can see this branch as a tracking branch. If not (as in my case with a single branch clone), add this branch to the tracking branch list by "git remote set-branches" with --add option:

- `git remote set-branches --add  <remote_name>  <branch_name>`

2. Fetch the branch you have added from the remote:

- `git fetch <remote_name> <branch_name>`
  Note: only after the new tracking branch was fetched from the remote, you can see it in the tracking branch list with `git branch -r`.

3. Create and checkout a new local branch with "checkout --track", which will be given the same "branch_name" as a tracking branch:

- `git checkout --track <remote_name>/<branch_name>`

Answer (score 17):

*Copied from the author's post:*

Use the `-t` option to `git remote add`, e.g.:

```
git remote add -t remote-branch remote-name remote-url
```

You can use multiple `-t branch` options to grab multiple branches.

Comment: Do you know how I can add and remove more branches to the remote once I used -t branch thing?

Answer (score 15):

If you want to change the default for "git pull" and "git fetch" to only fetch specific branches then you can edit .git/config so that the remote config looks like:

```
[remote "origin"]
  fetch = +refs/heads/master:refs/remotes/origin/master
```

This will only fetch master from origin by default.
See for more info: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-The-Refspec

EDIT: Just realized this is the same thing that the -t option does for git remote add. At least this is a nice way to do it after the remote is added if you don't want ot delete the remote and add it again using -t.

Comment: progit.org/book/ch9-5 link has moved to http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Internals-The-Refspec

Answer (score 15):

For the sake of completeness, here is an example command for a fresh checkout:

```
git clone --branch gh-pages --single-branch git://github.com/user/repo
```

As mentioned in other answers, it sets `remote.origin.fetch` like this:

```
[remote "origin"]
        url = git://github.com/user/repo
        fetch = +refs/heads/gh-pages:refs/remotes/origin/gh-pages
```

Answer (score 13):

The simplest way to do that

```
  git fetch origin <branch> && git checkout <branch>
```

Example: I want to fetch uat branch from origin and switch to this as the current working branch.

```
   git fetch origin uat && git checkout uat
```

Answer (score 12):

Let me put in my two pence with a twist to [MrMadsen's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51848403/3162788):

1. `git fetch <remote_name_or_url> <branch_name>`
2. `git checkout FETCH_HEAD -B <branch_name>`

The main advantage of these two lines over [MrMadsen's proposal](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51848403/3162788) is that it will even work if the branch already exists locally.

Comment: This worked! I kept getting `Cannot update paths and switch to branch at the same time.` error with other approaches suggested on this page.

Answer (score 6):

My workarounds:

```
git fetch --depth=1
git checkout <branch_name>
```

if you don't have a local clone:

```
git clone --depth 1 -b <branch_name> <repo_url>
```

Answer (score 5):

git version: 2.74

This is how I do it:

```
git remote add [REMOTE-NAME] [REMOTE-URL]
git fetch [REMOTE-NAME] -- [BRANCH]
```

Answer (score 5):

git version 2.16.1.windows.4

Just doing a **git fetch remoteRepositoryName branchName** `(eg: git fetch origin my_local_branch)` is enough. Fetch will be done and a new local branch will be created with the same name and tracking will be set to remote branch.

Then perform **git checkout branchName**

Comment: the branch doesn't appear under `git branch` until you checkout into it

Comment: You should be able to see the remote branch if you do a `git branch -a` (all branches)

Answer (score 5):

This way works for me.

fetch the remote branch of the target branch:

```
git fetch origin branch-name
```

check out the target branch:

```
git checkout -b branch-name origin/branch-name
```

Here, I tried to fetch release-20.10.08 successfully.

```
name:directory zgong$ git fetch release-20.10.04 release-20.10.04
fatal: 'release-20.10.04' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
WM-C02WM0T3HTD8:vdca_android_20_10_04_stable zgong$ git fetch origin release-20.10.04
From ssh://stash.trusted.visa.com:7999/vdcbc3a/vmcp-android-mobile-app
 * branch                  release-20.10.04 -> FETCH_HEAD
WM-C02WM0T3HTD8:vdca_android_20_10_04_stable zgong$ git checkout -b release-20.10.08 origin/release-20.10.08
fatal: 'origin/release-20.10.08' is not a commit and a branch 'release-20.10.08' cannot be created from it
WM-C02WM0T3HTD8:vdca_android_20_10_04_stable zgong$ git fetch origin release-20.10.08
remote: Counting objects: 637, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (320/320), done.
remote: Total 637 (delta 303), reused 465 (delta 202)
Receiving objects: 100% (637/637), 312.26 KiB | 262.00 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (303/303), done.
From ssh://stash.trusted.visa.com:7999/vdcbc3a/vmcp-android-mobile-app
 * branch                  release-20.10.08 -> FETCH_HEAD
 * [new branch]            release-20.10.08 -> origin/release-20.10.08
WM-C02WM0T3HTD8:vdca_android_20_10_04_stable zgong$ git checkout -b release-20.10.08 origin/release-20.10.08
M   VMCP/fmcore_android
M   VMCP/foundation_android
M   VMCP/mep_3ds_android
M   VMCP/mep_login_android
M   VMCP/mep_provisioning_and
Branch 'release-20.10.08' set up to track remote branch 'release-20.10.08' from 'origin'.
Switched to a new branch 'release-20.10.08'
```

Answer (score 4):

In my case, I wanted to fetch a branch without creating a new remote, so this worked:

`git fetch <remote url> <remote branch name>:<local branch name>`

Answer (score 3):

1. Pick any `<remote_name>` you'd like to use (feel free to use `origin`
   and skip step 1.)
2. `git remote add <remote_name> <remote_url>`
3. `git fetch <remote_name> <branch>`
4. Pick any `<your_local_branch_name>` you'd like to use. Could be the same as `<branch>`.
5. `git checkout <remote_name>/<branch> -b <your_local_branch_name>`

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 1):

The reply depends on what you want to accomplish.

1. If it is a one time deal from a different repository and you don't need a reference (e.g. to merge GitHub Pull Requests, where <remote_url> is like https://github.com/USER/REPO.git), then you can use:

   ```
   git checkout -b <local_branch> <local_branch_to merge_into>
   git pull <remote_url> <remote_branch>
   ```
2. If you want to update and track the branch you have to set first the remote and there are 4 alternatives:

   1. If you are cloning a new repository (e.g. working only on it)

      ```
      git clone --single-branch --branch remote_branch remote_url
      ```
   2. If you are adding a new remote to your working directory

      ```
      # multiple -t options are allowed
      git remote add -t <remote_branch> <remote_repo> <remote_url>
      ```
   3. If you are adding the branch restriction to an existing remote in your working directory

      ```
      # with --add it will add the branch instead of setting it
      # you can add multiple branches with multiple --add lines 
      # wildcards are allowed, 
      #   e.g. branch_v\* matching branch_v1, branch_v2, ...
      git remote set-branches [--add]  <remote_repo>  <remote_branch>
      ```
   4. You could also skip the restrictions because clone by default fetches only the main branch and remote add does not fetch branches. Buth then you'll have to mention the remote branch all the remote branch all the time you fetch the remote_repo.

      ```
      git remote add <remote_repo> <remote_url>
      ```

   After setting the remote you can fetch the remote branch, checkout and pull:

   ```
   # If you set only one <remote_branch> in the restrictions above (i.e no option 4), 
   # then you can omit it and still only <remote_branch> will be fetched
   git fetch <remote_repo> [<remote_branch>]
   # without -b the local branch name is guessed to be the same as the remote one
   git checkout --track [-b <local_branch>] <remote_repo>/<remote_branch>
   ```

The best command to check a remote and the branches that have been already or will be fetched is `git remote show <remote_repo>`. It prints the list of branches under "Remote branch:" and also tells you if they have been fetched and if they are tracked.

You can check the branch restrictions in a remote also by listing the known remote branches with `git branch -r`, in combination with `grep` if you have many remotes, or by checking the remote details in the git config file `.git/config`. It will contain a section like:

```
[remote "<remote_repo>"]
    url = <remote_url>
    fetch = +refs/heads/<remote_branch>:refs/remotes/<remote_repo>/<remote_branch>
```

Editing the config file will work to change the restrictions but I agree with @alexk that is not a good idea.

NOTE: If a branch is not in the list of branches of a remote (visible in `git remote show` or the config file), then you will not be able to have a reference to it, git will save it to the temporary FETCH_HEAD and you will not be able to track it or to use it directly in `git checkout`. This is the problem that brought me to this thread (the opposite of the one in the question): I cloned a repo with GitHub client `gh repo clone USER/REPO` and it added automatically "upstream", the repository forked from, restricted only to the branch "master". I was unable to checkout other branches and getting errors like "fatal: '<remote_repo>/<remote_branch>' is not a commit and a branch '<local_branch>' cannot be created from it". I fixed it with: `git remote set-branches <remote_repo> \*`.